# Vote to timeout

Tags: feature-request, chat, chat-timeout

Please allow us to vote to timeout a room if the discussion starts degenerating or otherwise going off-topic. Unfortunately this is a mods only feature and mods aren't always around.

I think six votes in five minutes should be enough.

Comment: Could you define "timeout"?

Comment: The topic of a channel should be whatever is being discussed in the channel at the time. There is no such thing as a discussion going off topic.

Comment: @Popular What happens when moderators hit the timeout picture as shown [here](http://i.imgur.com/cvmKC.png) -- the input box is hidden and numbers fade in counting down from 60 to 0. When this is finished, chatting may resume.

Answer (score 1):

Room owners can [now also put a room in timeout](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271267/a-guide-to-moderating-chat/271269#271269), so I don't think this feature request is relevant anymore.