# Add list of recent chat flags to /admin

Tags: feature-request, chat, moderator-tools, chat-flags

Chat has a list of moderator links on [/admin](https://chat.stackexchange.com/admin/).

Unfortunately, this page doesn't have a link to [/admin/recent-flags](https://chat.stackexchange.com/admin/recent-flags), the list of recent chat flags.  Every time I want to find this list, I always have to find either [this meta post by bluefeet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271267/a-guide-to-moderating-chat/271270#271270) or the [May 2016 moderator newsletter](https://stackmod.blog/2016/04/may-2016-newsletter/).

I change computers too frequently to rely on a bookmark, so I would appreciate any change that makes it easier to find this list.  The other tools mentioned in bluefeet's answer are already linked there, so it seems like the right place to add the link.

Could the recent flags list please be added to /admin?

Comment: Some browsers (e.g. Chrome) synchronize the bookmarks between different computers and devices. Just a thought. :-)