# How do I check if a chat flag has been reviewed?

Tags: support, chat, chat-flags

How do I check if a flag I’ve done in chat has been reviewed?

If I wasn’t busy at the time I flagged, I would have hung around and see if extra users came into the chat, but I was busy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to directly see this as a regular user, though obviously if the message you flagged has been deleted, the flag was handled. (I'm not sure what exactly happens if the user themselves deletes the message before the flag is handled, but that seems like a good outcome if you flagged it.)

Moderators have access to a [list of (all) recent chat flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301073/add-list-of-recent-chat-flags-to-admin), including moderator flags. If it's a regular chat flag, you could ask one of the other 10k users on the chat server if they still see a pending flag. (Though if you do that in the room itself, it might draw a reaction from the author of the message, especially if they know it's bordering on the problematic line, or over it.)