# Moderation Strike: Stack Overflow, Inc. cannot consistently ignore, mistreat, and malign its volunteers

Tags: discussion, status-review, community, company, moderation-strike

> ### Update
>
> On August 2nd, 2023, negotiations between community representatives and representatives of the company concluded with an agreement being reached. The details of the agreement can be found at [Moderation strike: Results of negotiations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391847/294691).
>
> On August 7th, 2023, based on the result of several polls held by various sections of the community, the coordinated call to strike concluded. Further details can be found at [Moderation strike: Conclusion and the way forward](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/392032).

---

### Introduction

As of today, June 5th, 2023, a large number of moderators, curators, contributors, and users from around Stack Overflow and the Stack Exchange network are initiating a general moderation strike. This strike is in protest of recent and upcoming changes to policy and the platform that are being performed by Stack Exchange, Inc.<sup>1</sup>
We have posted an [open letter](https://openletter.mousetail.nl/) addressed to Stack Exchange, Inc. The letter details which actions are being avoided, the main concerns of the signees, and the concrete actions that Stack Exchange, Inc. needs to take **to begin** to resolve the situation. Striking community members will refrain from moderating and curating content, including casting flags, and critical community-driven anti-spam and quality control infrastructure will be shut down.

However, the letter itself cannot contain all of our concerns, and we felt it was important to share some of the background and details that were not included in the letter in the interest of brevity. We also wanted to touch upon several points at the same time that are related to Stack Exchange, Inc.’s recent behavior.

### Background

#### A history of the Artificial Intelligence policy

On December 5th, 2022, Stack Overflow moderators instituted a [“temporary policy”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831) banning the use of ChatGPT in particular on the site. This was instituted due to the general inaccuracy of the answers, as well as that such posts violate the [referencing requirements](/help/referencing) of Stack Overflow. The moderator team kept an eye on community feedback to guide it, and support welled beneath this policy. Similar policies were enacted [across the network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384923).

Within the next several days, thousands of posts were removed and hundreds of users were suspended for violating this policy.

Over the next few months, Stack Exchange, Inc. staff assisted in the enforcement of this policy. This included [adding a site banner announcing the ban on these posts as well as editing and adding Help Center articles to mention this policy. Moderators were also explicitly given permission to suspend for 30 days directly in such cases](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421991/11107541), skipping the escalation process that is generally encouraged.

On May 29th, 2023 (a major holiday for moderators in the US, CA, UK, and possibly other locations), a post was made by a CM on the private Stack Moderators Team<sup>2</sup> (now [publicly published](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391626/historical-policy-on-the-use-of-gpt-detectors)). This post, with a title mentioning “GPT detectors”, focused on the rate of inaccuracy experienced by automated detectors aiming to identify AI- and specifically GPT-generated content - something that moderators were already well aware of and taking into account.

This post then went on to require an immediate cessation of issuing suspensions for AI-generated content and to stop moderating AI-generated content on that basis alone, affording only one exceptionally rare case in which it was permissible to delete or suspend for AI content. It was received extremely poorly by the moderators, with many concerns being raised about the harm it would do.

On May 30th, 2023, [a version of this policy was posted to Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389582/997587) and tagged [mod-agreement-policy](/questions/tagged/mod-agreement-policy), making this a binding moderator policy according to the [Moderator Agreement](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement). The policy on Meta Stack Exchange differs substantially from the version issued in private to the moderators. In particular, the public version of the policy conspicuously excludes the “requirements” made in private to immediately cease practically all moderation of AI-generated content.

#### The problem with the new policy on AI-generated content

The new policy, establishing that AI-generated content is *de facto* allowed on the network, is harmful in both what it allows on the platform and in how it was implemented.

The new policy **overrode established community consensus and previous CM support, was not discussed with any community members, was presented misleadingly to moderators and then even more misleadingly in public, and is based on unsubstantiated claims derived from unreviewed and unreviewable data analysis**. Moderators are expected to enforce the policy as it is written in private, while simultaneously being unable to share the specifics of this policy as it differs from the public version.

In addition to these issues in how Stack Exchange, Inc. went about implementing this policy, this change has direct, harmful ramifications for the platform, with many people firmly believing that allowing such AI-generated content masquerading as user-generated content will, over time, drive the value of the sites to zero.

#### A serious failure to communicate

Throughout the process of creating, announcing, and implementing this new policy, there has been a consistent failure to communicate on the part of Stack Exchange, Inc. There has been a lack of communication with moderators and a lack of communication with the community. When communication happened, it was one-sided, with Stack Exchange, Inc. being unwilling to receive critical feedback.

An offer by Philippe, the Vice President of Community, to hold a discussion in the Teachers’ Lounge moderator-only chatroom took days to be realized. During that conversation, certain concerns were addressed<sup>3</sup>, but the difficult questions remained unanswered – particularly about the lack of communication ahead of time.

#### The problem with AI-generated content

This issue has been talked about endlessly, both all around the Stack Exchange network and around the world, but we feel it’s important to highlight a few reasons why several communities, not just Stack Overflow, decided to ban AI-generated content. These reasons serve as the backbone not only for our moderation stance against AI-generated content, but also why we feel confused and betrayed by Stack Exchange, Inc.’s sudden decision to halt our efforts to enforce our community-supported decision to ban it.

To [reference Stack Overflow moderator Machavity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384429), AI chatbots are like parrots. ChatGPT, for example, doesn’t understand the responses it gives you; it simply associates a given prompt with information it has access to and regurgitates plausible-sounding sentences. It has no way to verify that the responses it’s providing you with are accurate. ChatGPT is not a writer, a programmer, a scientist, a physicist, or any other kind of expert our network of sites is dependent upon for high-value content. When prompted, it’s just stringing together words based on the information it was trained with. It does not *understand* what it’s saying. That lack of understanding yields unverified information presented in a way that sounds smart or citations that may not support the claims, if the citations aren’t wholly fictitious. Furthermore, the ease with which a user can simply copy and paste an AI-generated response simply moves the metaphorical “parrot” from the chatbot to the user. They don’t really understand what they’ve just copied and presented as an answer to a question.

Content posted without innate domain understanding, but written in a “smart” way, is dangerous to the integrity of the Stack Exchange network’s goal: To be a repository of high-quality question-and-answer content.

AI-generated responses also represent a serious honesty issue. Submitting AI-generated content without attribution to the source of the content, as is common in such a scenario, is plagiarism. This makes AI-generated content eligible for deletion per the [Stack Exchange Code of Conduct](/conduct/inauthentic-usage) and [rules on referencing](/help/referencing). However, in order for moderators to act upon that, they must identify it as AI-generated content, which the private AI-generated content policy limits to *extremely* narrow circumstances which happen in only a *very* low percentage of AI-generated content that is posted to the sites.

#### This isn’t just about the new AI policy

While a primary focus of the strike is the potential for the total loss of usefulness of the Stack Exchange platform caused by allowing AI-generated content to be posted by users, the strike is also in large part about a pattern of behavior recently exhibited by Stack Exchange, Inc.

The company has once again ignored the needs and established consensus of its community, instead focusing on [business pivots](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/05/31/ceo-update-paving-the-road-forward-with-ai-and-community-at-the-center/) at the expense of its own Community Managers, with many community requests for improved tooling and improving the user experience being left on the back burner. As an example, chat, one of the most essential tools for moderators and curators, is desperately out of date, with [two-minute, high improvement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301073/294691) changes being ignored for years.

Furthermore, the company has repeatedly announced changes that moderators deem would cause direct harm to the goals of the platform, this policy on AI-generated content among them. The community, including moderators and the general contributor base, was not consulted nor asked for input at any point before these changes were announced, phrased in a manner that indicated that there was no possibility of retraction or even a trial period.

Some of these planned changes have been temporarily held off due to controversy, this strike influencing those decisions, but that does not change the recent tendency of Stack Exchange, Inc. to make decisions affecting the core purpose of the site without consulting those most affected.

[The events of the last few weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389558/stack-exchange-is-failing-its-community) seem like history repeating itself. Stack Exchange, Inc. ventures into a new pursuit, [this time, generative AI](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388401/new-blog-post-from-our-ceo-prashanth-community-is-the-future-of-ai), in contrast with the community’s interests, makes a decision at odds with all feedback available to them, ceases communications with us, and we go on strike. This is similar to what happened last time the community moderators prepared to go on strike.

### How we resolve this

Even though the strike may end, many community members are not comfortable with returning to the status quo before the AI policy itself, if nothing else changes. The strike’s focus on the AI policy is not downplaying the significance of SE’s other actions. We deserve much more than just retracting the AI policy. [Stack Exchange already made promises after the 2019 debacle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343890/the-company-s-commitment-to-rebuilding-the-relationship-with-you-our-community) that they have since failed to meet. We are worried that Stack Exchange will continue down the same path once the situation calms down.

While the recent actions by Stack Exchange, Inc. are in conflict with the community and take a significant step backward in terms of the relationship between the company and the community, we do not think that our relationship is beyond repair. We do however worry that we are nearing the point at which it cannot be repaired anymore.

While it certainly may be true that the company wants to meet our needs, and wants to care for us, the reality is that this is not happening. It is time to wake up and realize what must be done. Stack Exchange, Inc. is not acting in our interest. It is time to do so.

#### What the striking users want

For the strike to end, the following conditions must be met:

- The AI policy change retracted and subsequently changed to a degree that addresses the expressed concerns and empowers moderators to enforce the established policy of forbidding generated content on the platform.
- Reveal to the community the internal AI policy given directly to moderators. The fact that you have made one point in private, and one in public, which differ so significantly has put the moderators in an impossible situation, and made them targets for being accused of being unreasonable, and exaggerating the effect of the new policy. Stack Exchange, Inc. has done the moderators harm by the way this was handled. The company needs to admit to their mistake and be open about this.
- Clear and open communication from Stack Exchange, Inc. regarding establishing and changing policies or major components of the platform with extensive and meaningful public discussion beforehand.
- Honest and clear communication from Stack Exchange, Inc. about the way forward.
- Collaborate with the community, instead of fighting it.
- [Stop being dishonest about the company’s relationship with the community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389653/blog-post-ceo-update-paving-the-road-forward-with-ai-and-community-at-the-cent).

#### A change in leadership philosophy toward the community

We need business leadership to meet minds with the community members and community managers, because currently, it appears that leadership ignores them.

Immediate financial concerns appear to drive feature development. The community also has feature development wants and needs, but no substantial consideration is given to those needs, let alone resource allocation. The lack of merit leadership gives to the community and CMs even leads to its own business decisions being reckless and harmful, like the AI policy.

Leadership needs a change in philosophy to one that treats the community as more than a product, and values its needs and expertise. Such a philosophy is evidently currently missing, and leadership takes the expertise of its own product for granted. Leadership needs to represent this philosophy in actually allocating resources based on community needs as well as its own, and informing its feature development using the expertise of the community. Development *can* be guided by both business *and* community needs!

### In conclusion

The sites on the Stack Exchange network are kept running smoothly by countless hours of unpaid volunteer work, and, in some cases, projects paid for out of pocket by community members. Stack Exchange, Inc. needs to remember that neglecting and mistreating these volunteers can only lead to a decrease in the goodwill and motivation of those contributing to the platform.

**A general moderation strike is being held until the concerns laid out in the open letter and this post are addressed. Moderators, curators, contributors, and users, you are welcome to join in by [signing your name](https://openletter.mousetail.nl) in the strike letter.**

**If you would like to sign the open strike letter, but do not have a Stack Overflow account, please reach out to [@mousetail](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/490835/mousetail) (start a new room).**

### Updates

[This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390106/261639) contains strike updates (representatives elected, reactions to the GPT data analysis posted by Philippe, conditions for ending the strike).

---

<sup>1</sup> While we’re aware that the legal name of the company is “Stack Exchange, Inc.”, the name “Stack Overflow” is more recognizable, and thus used in the open letter. The “Inc.” serves to demonstrate that our concerns lie with the corporate entity, and not the site itself, its moderators, or individual employees.

<sup>2</sup> Stack Exchange, Inc. provides a free [Stack Overflow for Teams](https://stackoverflowteams.com) instance for Stack Exchange moderators, allowing moderators to store and share private information, bug reports, documentation, and communication with SO staff.

<sup>3</sup> This includes another planned change to the foundational systems of the platform that has the potential to facilitate unprecedented levels of abuse. (This was referred to as “the second shoe” during the planning stages of the letter and the strike, as in “[waiting for the other shoe to drop](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wait_for_the_other_shoe_to_drop)”.) This has been delayed indefinitely while parts of the plan are reconsidered.

Comment: Hey, I'd love to sign the open letter but I can't without a Stack Overflow account. Is there any possibility to make some alternative sign-in method? I'd be happy to use my SE account or my Meta SE, for example. I'm active in moderation on three sites to varying degrees, and I anonymously edit many posts (mostly ELL and HNQ), so that's what I'll be stopping.

Comment: @bobble That’s an unintended issue on our part. Sorry for the inconvenience. Hopefully will be fixed soon.

Comment: "The AI policy change retracted and subsequently changed to a degree that addresses the expressed concerns and empowers moderators to enforce the established policy of forbidding generated content on the platform." That seems to be a very important point. Not only because it's difficult to achieve but also because it formally puts the striking mods against the now existing moderator policies. I hope a solution can be found.

Comment: @Andreasdetestscensorship Please add an option to indicate that someone supports removing the policy but doesn't want to participate in the strike. I'd like to sign the letter but due to its current phrasing it would state that I'm participating.

Comment: This looks like the karmic conclusion to the hystorical disagreement about what constitutes NAA (is an answer that answers a different question that the one asked or violates some requirements still an answer?) and what should be done with wrong/dangerous/irrelevant answers (downvote or delete?). Now the new "defense in absurdity" is claiming that one may not have the experience to see if an answer is wrong, even when they have.

Comment: I am surprised nobody has leaked the stated-in-private policy yet.

Comment: Stack Exchange moderators take their commitments seriously, @user3840170, and leaking private information is a massive breach of trust. Just because the company has broken trust does not mean that we will stoop to the level of leaking confidential information.

Comment: *The sites on the Stack Exchange network are kept running smoothly by countless hours of unpaid volunteer work, and, in some cases, projects paid for out of pocket by community members* that's crazy. Good (if any) old times are long gone. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosus .
Stop being exploited.

Comment: @Mithical I think the OP would consider leaking the information as whistleblowing, which has different ethics from just sharing confidential information.

Comment: @Sklivvz even if you want to appeal to that, most mods probably never opted-out of the arbitration clause - also know as "we choose our turf" (because I would expect them to not be mod if they did) and the company has already shown its "easy trigger" in the past, name-calling removed moderators on mainstream news outlet sites in an attempt to ruin their reputation.

Comment: @bobble perhaps it's *too* on-point, but the historical membrane between SO and SE servers that creates multiple, small friction points like your sign-in issue has been mentioned perennially by moderators as an issue deserving attention for at least a decade :facepalm:

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog there are several posts on the network where you can express the desire for the policy to be removed. The open letter, as well as this post, are specifically about the strike action, which you can join or not.

Comment: @Mithical: This would absolutely be whistleblowing not "leaking confidential information". Someone in the leadership is on the AI scam gravy train and trying to tank Stack Overflow in the process.

Comment: It would be a shame if after all this striking, we discovered that the striking moderators were not missed. Maybe some would discover hobbies, or plant a garden.

As a user, I want accurate answers, and I'm not pedantic about how they came to me. Those of us remaining during this "strike" will continue to respond to content on the basis of its content, not upon its imagined provenance.

Comment: Although I agree with you, I'm really skeptical about the strike's effectiveness. **Based on the company's actions in the last few years, it's pretty clear they don't care about quality or the community anymore**. And the community members who still care are seen as a burden they have to deal with. With the strike, SE has the perfect excuse to remove all diamonds and make new elections, making sure that all new mods will be aligned with their goals.

Comment: I'm concerned about the methods used to identify AI generated content and how accurate they are.  I don't believe there is any software that can do this with any kind of accuracy, banning users based on flawed identification software does not seem the way to go and this open letter seems to have not addressed these concerns.

Comment: @Caimen - Moderators do not rely on AI detectors to determine if a post is AI-generated. There are other heuristics used instead, and action is never taken solely because a purported AI detector claimed it was ChatGPT or whatever.

Comment: @Caimen Nobody has been banned. Suspensions have been doled out based on the basis of **human moderator review** of posts that have been flagged as _potentially_ LLM-generated.

Comment: @hkotsubo The intention is to make them aware by our lack of moderation purposes. It's not just the moderators that are strike. The majority of the core curators are on strike, including the bots we use, such as SmokeDetector.

Comment: @Caimen See the comments under [their new policy answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389583/357051). SE staff is lying to you. Do not trust the point of view which they have presented in that answer.

Comment: If you want to sign the letter but don't want to create a stack overflow account, DM me. I can add you manually @bobble

Comment: Regardless of AI policy I do not believe any LLM's should be permitted on any platforms at all until they can show their work, as in "Here is a full audit trail of how I reached this answer".

Comment: @agentv ".. respond to content on the basis of its content, not upon its [..] provenance." Just as a general stance I could live with that. But it's also about copyright and average quality. Sure, some human users also post low quality but the community here is concerned with mass production of low quality content. The ban is temporary, until AI gets better. And it probably gets better at some point. But until then we need the tools to keep the quality high and the company doesn't want to allow these being concerned more with collateral damage, at least it says. Who knows..

Comment: While I certainly agree that SE could and should have done better in 2019, that "debacle" does not rest solely on their shoulders - a substantial number of community members _and moderators_ were being openly transphobic, to the point that the only way to make the sites friendly to nonbinary people (among others) was for the company to step in. I'm absolutely all for demanding better on the actual core issues here, but let's not weaken our position by tying those important issues to cases where the company was ultimately the grownup in the room, and it was us that couldn't be trusted.

Comment: @Cascabel Most of what you said makes perfect sense - I saw some blatantly transphobic posts here on this site at the time. However, I disagree with your point that the company was "ultimately the grownup in the room" and that the community "couldn't be trusted" - many of those posts were being nuked by the community, not by staff.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Many of those posts were being _made by moderators_. I was on the receiving end of a significant amount of abuse from moderators. Attempts to shift policy starting from discussion among moderators were uniformly shot down. Yes, there were also community members moderating well, but the overall point stands.

Comment: @Cascabel I'm sorry to hear that with you being a (♦)-moderator on one of the sites yourself. As a regular user I have no knowledge on what's going on internally between the moderators, but I hope some good policy can be made. (although I don't understand -- if a supermajority of moderators are against transphobia why would policies being shot down?)

Comment: "A change in leadership." is probably the only thing that will improve the situation. i haven't seen anything that was aimed at improving the community in the past year. i absolutely think the current ceo is not fit for the role. it's rather ironic seeing "button styling" (still featured) and "moderator strike" next to each other, just shows their priorities.  oh, i'm sorry, "moderator action" - sure fooled everyone.

Comment: @user202729 I don't really feel comfortable getting too specific, but to try to rephrase my previous statement: collectively, both full communities and the internal moderator community came to conclusions that were inconsistent with the policy that was ultimately published. To try to steer back to the original point: holding SE accountable, great. Suggesting that it's always just been them who's out of touch, and the issue is purely "they're not doing what we say": meh.

Comment: @Alex re: "_i haven't seen anything that was aimed at improving the community in the past year_" -  see [Plagiarism flag and moderator tooling has launched to Stack Overflow!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423749/11107541)

Comment: I see a lot of diamonds among the list of people who have signed the open letter, but without clicking on each name individually, there seems to be no way to tell which sites are represented among those diamonds.  Is there a way to make that information more readily available?

Comment: "SE Inc. cannot consistently ignore, mistreat, and malign its volunteers" <- It's been doing that for quite a while. I'd rephrase that as "SE Inc. cannot _be allowed to_ ignore, mistreat and malign" etc.

Comment: Such a shame to see how disconnected SE Inc. is with its own moderator network and how issues like this crop up time and time again.

Comment: What exactly are non-diamond strikers not doing?

Comment: @Someone read the open letter: "Raising and handling flags, Closing or voting to close posts, Deleting or voting to delete posts, Reviewing tasks in the various review queues," etc.

Comment: @starball so upvoting and downvoting continues as normal? I did read that, but I've read comments from a couple people saying things like "I would upvote this, but I'm on strike"

Comment: @Someone to be more precise, everyone on strike does what they choose to, there is no official "guideline" on how to behave (apart from the general rule of not doing something that would be considered a punishable offence under normal circumstances anyway) - we are not SE, after all. Some chose to abstain from *any and all* activity, some - only from moderation duties (VTC/VTR/VTD/reviews/edits). Some chose to stop on all sites, some decided to continue moderating meta sites.

Comment: I know why I didn't change my profile image after [the Monica incident](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965/273829)...

Comment: so how is the strike going ? are normal users joining it ? do we have stats about it or just the subscribers of the open letter ?

Comment: @pippo1980ONSTRIKE _are normal users joining it_ yes, me at least - didn't do any content/curation related action since the strike started and I signed the open letter :) there also are other high frequency high expert contributors to SO - which I know - doing the same .. nothing

Comment: @pippo1980ONSTRIKE have a look at [close review stats page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats). Currently it shows me 7 (seven) reviewers with all but the top one having less than 15 reviews. Compare this to 90,000 users having sufficient reputation to do close reviews. How do you think it happened that only 7 of these decided to review today

Comment: ...[low quality answer stats page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/stats) looks slightly better on a surface, it shows decent looking list of reviewers with half-decent amount of reviews shown for them. "246 needs review" message also may appear okayish... but it just happened that I saw this very page [10 days ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/424895/839601) and it displayed 54 - like, about five times less of what I see today. Looks like folks who joined the strike, signed or not, made some impact, yes

Comment: As a random non-moderator and occasional meta reader, this makes no sense from SE's point of view.  If they have the data, they would surely share it.  At least with the moderators (as they have proven over and over again that they don't lead private data).  The only thing that "connects all the dots" (to me) is that SE had planned to make this move and purposely planned to make the moderators take the fall.  They figured no one would call them on their statements.  They can't back down (because this was the plan) but they don't really have any data to share.  Hard spot to be in.

Comment: I think this was well-written and thoughtful, but have the following comments (mostly geared toward StackExchange): 1. Consider me as a ***scab***. I would love to be a moderator in place of any who strike. 2. I believe fighting AI and trying to block it is incredibly silly and non-sustainable. Do you usually ban tools? Is this really so different from any other resource? If StackExchange allows itself to linger in the past while other sites take an AI-first strategy with greatly enhanced ability to improve questions, provide answers, and mine data, then I'm using the other sites.

Comment: I don't see any serious changes being proposed. If you *need* to see real change because the mods can't keep pace with new AI-generated answers then here is a serious resolution: Have several prompts before the new user posts their answer warning them that posting an AI-generated answer results in a permanent ban of their account. If they post the AI-generated answer then permanently ban their account. I think perma-banning their IP is too harsh. But forcing them to create a new account from another e-mail address is a pain, and so this method will result in positive change. Am I wrong?

Comment: Per @agentv: "It would be a shame if after all this striking, we discovered that the striking moderators were not missed. ...  As a user, I want accurate answers, and I'm not pedantic about how they came to me." I agree. I have had questions blocked simply because some moderator decided that they didn't like the wording of my questions, irrespective of the fact that the questions were asked clearly enough for a number of readers to easily understand and answer them. I hope that these nitpicky, overly pedantic moderators would not return from the strike. And I do indeed support the strike.

Comment: From @Shawn: "The great war between the humans and the robots begins..." It's simply a war between humans and other humans. The "robots" in question have no free will and no intelligence and no minds, and they are simply tools that are being utilized by humans. Calling this a robot/human war is like calling efforts at traffic-safety enforcement a "war between cars and humans".

Comment: My two cents. Since I started using ChatGPT for coding, I stopped asking questions on Stackoverflow. I think that Stackoverflow has to find a way to integrate AI otherwise it will be lost especially when AI models will be more accurate and provide better results.

Comment: @CyberJ "_when AI models will be more accurate and provide better results._" data needed on that claim.

Answer (score 507):

#### Background from a striking SO mod who handled 10000+ GPT flags

I’m a Stack Overflow moderator coming here to give more details on what management has said that’s helped caused me to decide to join the strike, and to give details from my own personal experience handling several thousand of the warnings and suspensions we’ve done at Stack Overflow for ChatGPT-copy-paste abuse.

And I’m framing this as a response to [a comment elsewhere from company management way back in December](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421880/how-can-we-determine-whether-an-answer-used-chatgpt/421946#comment938662_421946) that now looks to have been an unintentional “tell” from management that they may have already started musing way back then about plans to frame it all as a misguided *“witch hunt”*.

So, to be very clear: The massive effort and hours the curators/flaggers and elected moderators spent together over the last 6 months very successfully stemming the ChatGPT copy-paste tide and shielding ***our* community’s users** from all that junk never in, any way shape or form, came anywhere close to actually resembling anything like a *“witch hunt”* or any other kind of malicious or hysterical misguided analogy that management might want to try to smear us with now.

The reality is instead this:

**We’ve been very accurately identifying the ChatGPT posts with an extremely low number of false positives. And I say that as someone who handled a very very large number of the flags.**

For support of the assertion above, please really do take time to read on here.

##### (Non)Use of any detection tools

I want to take a moment here now to respond specifically to the continuing nonsense insinuations (smears) from management (repeated to the media even today) that we have been over-relying on various detection tools that “have an alarmingly high rate of false positives” and their “decision to require that moderators stop using that tool [sic]”.

So, let me make clear:

**In the thousands of cases I handled, I never ever used any of the detection tools.**

That is, not only did I not “over rely” on detection tools, **I never relied on them at all.**

And in cases where the flaggers had included scores from any detection tools in their flag comments, **I even completely ignored whatever score information the flaggers provided** — to the point that I would actually stop reading the flag comments at the point where they were providing score information, because I found no use at all for it.

So not only could it be said of me that I am one of the moderators whose “own analyses were in use as well” — I can say that **my “own analysis” was *exclusively* in use, with zero reliance on any detector information.**

##### Numbers and assertions

To help clear up any doubts on whether I know whereof I speak, here are some numbers:

- Conservatively speaking, for the last 6 months (since the beginning of December 2022) every single day I have been spending **40 minutes a day just on moderating ChatGPT flags**. That works out to 120 hours in total that I’ve personally spent on them so far.
- And in those hours I’ve spent on this week after week, I’ve looked at multiple thousands of ChatGPT-flagged posts: in the order of **10000 or even 15000** at this point.

And so I do now assert that in the many hours I've spent actually looking at the ChatGPT-flagged posts, and from the many thousands of those posts that I have actually closely and carefully scrutinized in detail, I have in fact learned to recognize the ChatGPT copy-paste cases (including many of the ones whose content the posters had edited before pasting in, to intentionally obscure the provenance) and I can in fact say this:

**I assert: I can, with a very high level of confidence and a very low level of false positives, very effectively identify answers whose provenance is ChatGPT or other AI.**

And all that leads me to finish with an invitation…

##### An invitation to management

To anyone in management who claims the elected moderators have been getting it wrong for the last 6 months, with an unacceptably high rate of false positives, and who wants to challenge my personal assertions about how accurately I can identify the ChatGPT cases: I invite you to work together with me over several days looking at least some several dozens of ChatGPT flags as they come in.

Alternatively, rather than looking at new flags as they come in, I invite anyone
to go together through the logs of my moderation activities, and examine some significantly-sized random sample at least of the thousands of ChatGPT flags I have handled.

Either way, let’s spend time scrutinizing the actual content of the flagged posts together, and actually honestly talking together in good faith about which posts we think we can agree are highly likely not the poster’s own original work.

Until anybody who questions how well we’ve been handling the ChatGPT flags actually does something concrete like what’s described above, waving vague suggestions about possible “witch hunts” and other slanders around under the noses of the elected moderators and flaggers is completely **irresponsible** at best — but in reality, in combination with other indirect accusations and aggressions that key company reps driving company messaging around this have slung at the elected moderators, it is **completely unconscionable and completely unprincipled.**

Comment: As a moderator on a smaller site, seeing the numbers you posted about the amount of AI-flagged posts is... incredible.

Comment: I've flagged quite a few ChatGPT answers, and sideshowbarker has indeed handled a huge proportion of them. From my end, I can also say I've never flagged based on any detection tool -- after you look at a number of ChatGPT responses, it becomes obvious what is ChatGPT (and if I'm wrong about this, I'd like to see examples of false positives). I guess SO's fear is that when users push back and insist "No I didn't use ChatGPT" then SO has no _tangible_ proof that the user in fact used ChatGPT.

Comment: This answer is awesome. Great read. One could possibly create a training set for humans to learn to recognize AI generated content.

Comment: It would be interesting to set you up in a blind trial and see what your accuracy rate is on content known to be human generated vs content known to be AI generated.  I'll bet you fare way better than the detectors they are calling out.

Comment: @StephenOstermilleronStrike IMO this is a big bit of what SE is missing in the current moment. Many times, both privately and publicly, mods have asked staff to run a trial like that. No such trial of moderators' abilities has been conducted.

Comment: *"[...] striking SO mod who handled 10000+ GPT flags"* - I knew this was you immediately  Like tdy, you handled all (or most) of my ChatGPT flags, that also didn't use any tooling, but a combination of gut feeling, previous post history (if any), timeline of activity (multiple multi-paragraph posts in the span of a few seconds), etc. I'm glad to hear you (and I hope other moderators) used your best judgement and not some tool, and wanted to take a second to thank you; since ChatGPT came onto the scene, moderation here has probably been... difficult, but we, the users, appreciate you 

Comment: I- like tdy- never used ChatGPT scanners / detectors. When I flag something I think is ChatGPT, I just use my own sense and subject-matter expertise.

Comment: After sleeping over it: it could still be that AI scanners indirectly played a tiny role here. After all you say that many flagged posts you trained on included a score in the message. One could assume that the flagged posts were selected partly by scanners, which means the composition of the training data is affected by AI scanners. Another thing is the ground truth. How does anyone know the ground truth here unless it's a test like proposed by Stephen Ostermiller in a comment above? I mean where does the "very high level of confidence" come from if the ground truth is not known? Or is it?

Comment: FWIW, I have flagged hundreds of AI posts on SO and always detected and flagged those posts solely using my own brain, not tools. Occasionally, I have used detection tools, but only to see how well those tools work rather than means of detection or confirmation.

Comment: Like for regular plagiarism, I flag ChatGPT posts when I encounter them by chance (I didn't hunt for them (past tense intentional)). They are easier to spot than regular plagiarism due to ChatGPT's very distinct writing style (for instance, the echoing back of the question (in a slightly different form)). I have ***never*** used any tools for this, only my own brain. And I always look for supporting evidence before I flag. And thank you, *sideshowbarker*, for handling all those flags! The word has become devalued by overuse, but it is very much appreciated.

Comment: Worth stating: I've been consciously leaving the CGPT flags to others precisely because I missed the experience of the initial wave and  trust the judgement of the moderators who picked up the bulk of them far more than my own judgement on the matter

Comment: I have submitted numerous ChatGPT flags that were promptly and effectively handled by sideshowbarker. I feel we've worked together effectively to help protect StackOverflow. Now I will join the strike by ceasing all flagging and letting the site stew in its own juices.

Comment: I submitted many chatGPT flags that were handled by you. Although I used the detection tools just to see how they worked, I never gave them any credence. Firstly, it's easy to recognize when something likely had its start with chatGPT. It jumps out at you. Then I'd check their answer history, frequently there is a gap with mostly monosyllabic answers followed by more recent wordy flowing chatGPT-looking answers. Finally, I actually ran the questions through chatGPT, and only when one of its answers was almost verbatim copy-and-pasted did I flag the answer. No witch hunt here.

Comment: With all of my flags handled by you, in a timely fashion, the one that sat in queue *for an entire day* got me curious as to what's going on. That's why I'm here. Until reading the numbers, I'd assumed that AI-powered rep-whoring were a niche sport. That was naïve. As for my personal flagging principles: `1` Never flag content you cannot validate, and `2` flagged content must be (at least in part) verifiably incorrect. I'm impartial about tool usage; I just never found myself in need of looking for one. I wonder what led SE Inc. into assuming we were all just mindless lemmings...

Comment: *I can, with a very high level of confidence and a very low level of false positives, very effectively identify answers whose provenance is ChatGPT or other AI.*  How?  There's no way to confirm any of your guesses.  You are basically saying you make these judgments based on your gut, and your gut tells you that your gut is right.  Unless you're saying that you used ChatGPT to reproduce the flagged answers word-for-word?  You don't give any description here of your method at all.

Comment: I haven't read everything on this page. Maybe I'm missing something, but is there any evidence that any of this actually happened? As far as I can see, there isn't a link to even one AI - generated answer, let alone 10,000. What am I missing?

Comment: @AdamRubinson Here's one [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76395088/1889329). Feel free to have a look at the author's previous contributions and take an educated guess at what might have happened in the 6 months since their last post that turned them from someone that doesn't care about grammar, punctuation, or formatting into someone capable of writing perfect English text, perfectly paced and formatted, not missing a single punctuation mark.

Comment: I would like to see that reliability quantified with answers known to be produced by ChatGPT4 or not. Would you be able to tell that https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76925/ridge-regression-in-r-where-coefficients-are-penalized-toward-numbers-other-than/618452#618452 was ChatGPT4 produced, unless I disclosed it? More importantly, would you have a problem with that answer, given that it is correct & much better than the other answers? And could you tell it's a correct answer?

Comment: Same for this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48119360/performant-2d-sdl-or-opengl-graphics-in-r-for-fast-display-of-raster-image-using, that I never got an answer to after 5 years & ChatGPT4 was able to answer in seconds...

Comment: Why do you need Stack Exchange Inc. to run such a blind trail? Such a thing could also be set up between moderators themselves.

Comment: @TomWenseleers Your examples aren't relevant to the ChatGPT policy. We've always been allowed to use CGPT, test its output, and write a verified solution based on that output. The ban/strike is about thousands of users **copy-pasting** CGPT output and basically spamming unverified junk.

Comment: @tdy The exact conditions under which that ban applied were not clearly stated - the headline alone is Temporary policy: ChatGPT is banned, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned/421913#421913. If the policy had been "The posting of answers generated by ChatGPT without any manual verification is not allowed, but we encourage the use of ChatGPT if adequate steps are undertaken to ensure the correctness of the provided answer, including verifying that any code works" I would have agreed...

Comment: @tdy My answer here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76925/ridge-regression-in-r-where-coefficients-are-penalized-toward-numbers-other-than/618452#618452 was literally a copy and paste of what ChatGPT had written by the way (but I did manually verify that the code actually worked & that the maths was correct). Same for the SDL & OpenGL & rdyncall code I included in my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48119360/performant-2d-sdl-or-opengl-graphics-in-r-for-fast-display-of-raster-image-using

Comment: @TomWenseleers If you disagree with the [Meta announcement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned/421913#421913)'s title, I'd suggest posting there instead. It's worth discussing, just not related to the strike at hand.

Comment: @TomWenseleers If you're trying to provide counterexamples for GPT detection, SE is accusing the mods of being too aggressive (false positives) while you're suggesting the opposite (false negatives). So even if your [ridge regression answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/618452/313631) were truly a false negative (which I doubt due to some uncharacteristic punctuation/capitalization/grammar), it would actually support the mods here. FP and FN are inversely related by nature.

Comment: @tdy Well yes I'll discuss this there. My point - aside from the shoddy accuracy ((TP+TN) / (TP+TN+FP+FN)) - is simply that questions should just be judged based on their correctness, not on whether or not they were produced by ChatGPT...

Comment: If this answer is accurate, why are the moderators on strike?  They should quit altogether.  But then I suppose SE would replace them with moderator bots.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk "Finally, I actually ran the questions through chatGPT ..." That sounds like an awful lot of time that you invested in flagging GPT content. I don't want to diminish the effort in any way but can you say how much time you approximately spent for every GPT flag you created by this method?

Comment: We're on strike because we want to be able to keep doing this, to keep making the sites better, @dougp. If we're not allowed to do that, the next step will be quitting altogether, but we thought we should at least *try* some last-ditch efforts before abandoning ship altogether. We're not concerned that we'll be replaced with moderator bots. They might as well replace us with random number generators or nothing. At that point, the site will be dead anyway. We're attempting to head off the site we know, love, and have poured *thousands upon thousands* of hours into over the years from collapsing

Comment: "As for my personal flagging principles: 1 Never flag content you cannot validate, and 2 flagged content must be (at least in part) verifiably incorrect." @Tim even *verifiably correct* content can be *completely and utterly inappropriate* for the site (and worthy of flagging, and worthy of sanctions for its poster), in multiple ways. Most notably, it could violate Code of Conduct.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel  indeed. I just flagged a question by someone who wanted us to assist them in setting up a human trafficking scheme for example. Highly inappropriate, likely even illegal.

Comment: @jwenting That sounds like an excellent example of what __not__ to flag, during a strike. Let it surface; let it be visible; let the company see what pops up on their platform if they push away their curators and moderators.

Comment: @AndreasdetestsAIhype and let crime (literally) run rampant?

Comment: @jwenting Yes. That’s what a strike is.

Comment: Unless you can establish your own false positive rate, your assessment of your own moderation is unfortunately irrelevant. Moderators are making assumptions without data and accusing SE of doing the same thing. CGPT is **one** LLM. You absolutely cannot identify content from LLMs *in general*. If you can prove you can, go ahead.

Comment: @tdy No, the issue isn't being too aggressive, the issue is being biased. Bias produces both false positives and false negatives in a patterned way. SE is clearly most interested in preventing false positives since they harm users. False negatives, if they are correct and good answers, are objectively harmless.

Comment: @sideshowbarker clearly you've done a lot of excellent work here as a volunteer.  Unfortunately, the dynamics of the situation means you have no particular leverage or bargaining power over SE.  It's great you've written up these details, but on a personal note you might do better to leverage your talents in a more remunerative way *while also* helping others.

Comment: Ultimately, I think the misunderstanding between the parties is that SE turned into a knowledge sharing platform between peers to a platform being (ab)used for giving for free 1st world brain power/free work to low quality questions of the 3rd world. It boosts user numbers, however no one likes it, even those at the receiving end.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum  Your revision comment was unnecessarily rude, given the existing content in the answer, but turned out to be useful :-)

Answer (score 209):

Here's a list of per-site meta discussions related to the strike (largely gathered from [searching "`is:q created:2023-05-30.. strike [discussion]`" on stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+created%3A2023-05-30..+strike+%5Bdiscussion%5D), sorted based on [site traffic](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic), and updated on a best-effort-basis. <sup><sub>stackexchange.com search seems bugged and shows fewer items than the count it returns. I've seen enough bugs now to just not be surprised.</sub></sup>):

- Meta Stack Exchange:

  - This Q&A
  - [Moderation Strike update: Data dumps, choosing representatives, GPT data, and where we’re holding](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390106/997587)
  - [Would the striking moderators welcome a user strike? Should we, the users, go on strike?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390412/997587)

  - [Does the strike letter oppose AI?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390585/997587)
  - [What is needed for users to trust the Stack Exchange company?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390623/997587)
  - [Are users being suspended for being on strike?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391148/997587)
  - [Does the company acknowledge misusing the press, and why won't it agree on a no-comment policy?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391220/997587)
  - [Does the company claim that every article the press made on ongoing issues wasn't requested by them and was instead an unsolicited initiative?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391221/997587)
  - [Mod strike: Is it realistic to require a no-comment press policy?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391255/997587)

  - [Moderation strike: Results of negotiations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391847/997587)
  - [Does the Charcoal team plan to run SmokeDetector again?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391871/997587)
  - [What do you feel like is still missing to end the strike?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391925/997587)

  - [What kind of percentages are reasonable for moderator consensus on the company violating the Mod Agreement?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391939/997587)
  - [Moderation strike: Conclusion and the way forward](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/392032/997587)
- Stack Overflow:

  - (mirror of the above post): [Moderation Strike: Stack Overflow, Inc. cannot consistently ignore, mistreat, and malign its volunteers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425000/11107541)
  - [How is Stack Overflow Inc. prepared for a possible moderation strike by community elected moderators on June 5?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424984/11107541)
  - [What has happened to lead moderators to consider striking?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424979/11107541)
  - [What is the impact of the moderation strike?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425115/11107541)
  - [What can "ordinary" Stack Overflow users do to support the moderator strike?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425277/11107541)
  - [Could SE management conduct moderator elections with reduced requirements in response to the ongoing moderation strike?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425311/11107541)
  - [Moderation strike: how is the discussion going between the moderators and Stack Overflow, Inc?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425366/11107541)
  - [How can we handle troublesome contributors during the moderation strike?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425722/11107541)
  - [How do our moderators respond to the result of negotiations?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425908/11107541)
  - [Is Stack Overflow back to normal moderation?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425968/11107541)
- Unix & Linux: [General moderators' strike](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7092/550426)
- Ask Ubuntu:

  - [Stack Exchange general moderation strike: the effects on Ask Ubuntu](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/20325/1624654)
  - [I'm going on a general moderation strike due to the new AI-content policy forced upon us by SE](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/20324/1624654)
  - [Homepage spammed](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/20337/1624654)
  - [Decline in AU quality](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/20348/1624654)
  - [Are we there yet? 8 weeks on strike](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/20355/1624654)
- Super User: [General moderators' strike](https://meta.superuser.com/q/15021/1749748)
- Mathematics:

  - [Moderator Strike](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35763/926489)
  - [General Moderation Strike: Mathematics StackExchange moderators are participating](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35765/926489)
  - [Moderation strike update, and flags](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35823/926489)
  - [It is possible to add a banner indicating there is currently a moderation strike?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35858/926489)
  - [Moderation Strike Resolution](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35908/926489)
- Server Fault: [Labor action notice](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/9883/993961)
- Stack Overflow en español: [Huelga de moderación en la red de Stack Exchange](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5534/312662)
- Database Administrators: [Ongoing Moderation Strike](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3528/264529)
- Cross Validated: [June 5 General Moderation Strike: Recap, Possible roles, consequences and other relevant info](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6511/373726)
- Academia:

  - [Academia.SE Moderation Strike](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5286/165557)
  - [Moderation strike](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/196930/165557) (posted to the main site)
  - [What is the impact of the moderation strike on Academia.SE?](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5292/165557)
  - [What is the best way for high rep users to support the moderation strike?](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5298/165557)
  - [After a month of moderator strike, is there any update on the situation?](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5302/165557)
  - [Strike stopgap -- will this work, and is it OK?](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5317/165557)
  - [Moderation Strike is Over](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5329/165557)
- Arqade:

  - [Community Moderator Strike](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16790/297372)
  - [Solidarity: what does it mean to us?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16803/297372)
  - [Community Moderation Strike - The Return of the Arqade Mods](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16846/297372)
- MathOverflow:

  - [Stack Exchange moderation strike](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5667/495228)
  - [Moderation strike update 1](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5692/495228)
  - [Moderation strike update 2](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5703/495228)
  - [Moderation strike update 3](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5716/495228)
  - [Moderation strike update 4](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5720/495228)
  - [Moderation strike update 5 : the results of negotiations](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5733/495228)
  - [Moderation strike update 6 and last : back to work](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5737/495228)
- Role-Playing Games:

  - [Stack Exchange general moderation and curation strike begins today](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12444/79881)
  - [How do our strike-participating community members feel about the moderation-strike negotiation results?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12467/79881)
  - [What was the impact of the moderation strike on site activity?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12474/79881)
- Web Applications: [Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange Moderators Strike](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5055/305006)
- Science Fiction & Fantasy: [Sci-Fi moderators on AI content strike](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13926/159649)
- Aviation: [How much is Aviation Stack Exchange involved in the moderation strike?](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4455/67175)
- Bicycles:

  - [Stack Exchange Moderation Strike](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1514/68031)
  - [Moderation Strike Update](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1521/68031)
- Workplace: [No need for drama](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7223/137881)
- Cryptography: [Moderator strike due to SE forcing AI-moderation policy](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1660/105389)
- Seasoned Advice: [Are our mods taking part in the walkout?](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3811/102370)
- Music: Practice & Theory: [General Moderation Strike!](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3958/89547)
- Astronomy: [June 5 Strike - Who, What, Why, and how to join](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/912/48784)
- Bioinformatics: [Notification of Mod action on SE](https://bioinformatics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/338/16763)
- Bitcoin: [Notice: I’m participating in the Moderation Strike](https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1168/138593)
- Computational Science: [Moderation & curation strike: Mistrust, mistreat, and harmful imposed policies](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/645/44539)
- Retrocomputing: [The Stack Exchange data dump has been switched off](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1202/26010)
- Personal Finance & Money: [I will be joining the moderator strike](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3106/120291)
- Biology: [Moderators and community curators are on strike - how will it affect the site?](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4353/74042)
- Chess: [June 5 Strike - Who, What, When, Why, and How to Join](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1198/33971)
- History: [Where is HSE regarding the current strike?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4446/60097)
- Writing: [June 2023 Writing Challenge: Voices of Protest](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2577/57178)
- Physical Fitness: [The Stack Moderator Strike](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/q/909/39221)
- Literature: [Special thanks to Mithical for their role in helping to resolve the recent moderation strike](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1786/17802)
- Medical Sciences: [MedicalSciences.SE Moderation Strike](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1408/26252)
- Arts & Crafts: [Community Moderator Strike](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/q/617/16042)
- Sustainable Living: [Community Moderator Strike](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/q/427/14718)
- Programming Language Design & implementation: 
  [How is the strike going to impact PLDI?](https://languagedesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/348/251)

Honourable mentions:

- Community Building main site: [What could be the way out when interests of content curators and company drastically clash over ChatGPT content?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/q/3429/6888)
- Law main site: [What 'specific legal meaning' does the word "strike" have?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/93045/48193)
- Puzzling main site:

  - [Moderation strike: a tired lunatic (4)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/121093/81581)
  - [Solidarity with the Moderation Team (A Cryptic Division Puzzle)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/121169/81581)
- Blog posts by users I find notable <sup><sub>(yes, I know these aren't meta discussions, but this is my post, so too bad hehe)</sub></sup>:

  - Monica Cellio: [Stack Overflow is alienating its community again](https://cellio.org/blog/2023/stack-overflow-strike)
  - Jon Ericson: [Stack Exchange moderator strike](https://jlericson.com/2023/05/31/mod_strike.html)
  - Jon Ericson: [Why I'm signing the Stack Overflow strike letter](https://jlericson.com/2023/06/04/signing_on.html)
  - Jon Ericson: [How's the Stack Overflow strike going?](https://jlericson.com/2023/06/07/strike_progress.html)
  - Jon Ericson: [What Stack Overflow is telling employees about the strike](https://jlericson.com/2023/06/12/internal_messages.html)
  - Jon Ericson: [The data dump diversion](https://jlericson.com/2023/06/19/data_dump.html)
  - Jon Ericson: [Why AI is a problem on Stack Overflow](https://jlericson.com/2023/06/26/problem_ai.html)
  - Jon Ericson: [Stack Overflow's CEO doesn't understand Stack Overflow](https://jlericson.com/2023/07/26/not_understanding.html)
  - Jon Ericson: [Stack Overflow's strike is over (But its problems persist)](https://jlericson.com/2023/08/10/strike_over.html)

Comment: Not really about the strike per sé, but [Physics.SE remains a site by humans, for humans](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14438/physics-se-remains-a-site-by-humans-for-humans)

Comment: I contribute a third thread from AskUbuntu, if it's accepted: https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/20318

Comment: @Levente That's not directly about the strike.

Comment: should we also add mod resignment because of this?

Comment: @justANewbie to keep the answer consistent, only if there is a meta post about it. (not another section in this answer.)

Comment: From the blog posts: "The public post kind of back-handedly called moderators bigots, too. I guess at least this time they didn't smear anyone by name. But still... ick." Hearing this from Monica is... painful.

Comment: Tangentially related: [A user seems to be trolling many SE sites with AI-generated answers; what should I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391584/a-user-seems-to-be-trolling-many-se-sites-with-ai-generated-answers-what-should)

Answer (score 162):

So far, this is the closest thing that we have to an official response from the company, found in [an article on Dev Class](https://devclass.com/2023/06/05/stack-overflow-volunteer-moderators-down-tools-over-secret-new-policy-that-obstructs-removal-of-ai-generated-content/).

Speaking for myself, this is not a good start.

> The trigger for the current crisis was an instruction on Monday last
> week (a public holiday) to Stack Overflow moderators in an official
> but private forum,  “Moderators were informed, via pinned chat
> messages in various moderator rooms (not a normal method), to view a
> post in the Moderator Team that instructed all moderators to stop
> using AI detectors (as outlined above) in taking moderation actions,”
> said a post. The details of the instruction are not public. VP of
> Community Philippe Beaudette posted that “AI-generated content is not
> being properly identified across the network,” that “the potential for
> false positives is very high,” and “internal evidence strongly
> suggests that the overapplication of suspensions for AI-generated
> content may be turning away a large number of legitimate contributors
> to the site.” He said moderators had been asked to “apply a very
> strict standard of evidence to determining whether a post is
> AI-authored when deciding to suspend a user.” However, the moderators
> claim that a description of the policy posted by Beaudette “differs
> greatly from the Teams guidance … which we’re not allowed to publicly
> share.”

There is no evidence that this is true.

Although there is evidence that some detectors have false positives, this shouldn't be news to moderators and is something that has been discussed. It's why we don't rely exclusively on the detectors, but on other moderator tooling as well as our experience and expertise with the content on each of our communities.

I also don't see evidence that the people posting generated content are legitimate contributors. Of the people that I personally suspended, 1 had previous positive contributions. When someone is suspended, they can also appeal by responding to the moderator message. No one did. I can't speak for all moderators on all sites, but my understanding is that the number of accounts with prior positive contributions and accounts that responded to suspensions is low.

> In a statement sent to Dev Class, Stack Overflow’s CEO Prashanth
> Chandrasekar told us:
>
> “A small number of moderators (11%) across the Stack Overflow network
> have stopped engaging in several activities, including moderating
> content. The primary reason for this action is dissatisfaction with
> our position on detection tools regarding AI-generated content.
>
> “Stack Overflow ran an analysis and the ChatGPT detection tools that
> moderators were previously using have an alarmingly high rate of false
> positives. Usage of these tools correlated to a dramatic upswing in
> suspensions of users with little or no prior content contributions;
> people with original questions and answers were summarily suspended
> from participating on the platform. These unnecessary suspensions and
> their outsize impact on new users run counter to our mission and have
> a negative impact on our community.
>
> “We stand by our decision to require that moderators stop using the
> tools previously used. We will continue to look for alternatives and
> are committed to rapid testing of those tools.
>
> “Our moderators have served this community for many years, and we
> appreciate their collective decades of service. We are confident that
> we will find a path forward. We regret that actions have progressed to
> this point, and the Community Management team is evaluating the
> current situation as we work hard to stabilize things in the short
> term,” he added.

The number of moderators may be small, but includes the most engaged moderators across some of the most active sites on the network. It also discounts the impact of deactivating various notification tools and anti-spam bots that users run on new posts to mitigate their impact. The statement trivializes who is participating and what this participation will look like to visitors to the platform.

I don't think that the position on detection tools is the issue. Moderators have known, since the very beginning, about the limitations in the tools used to detect algorithmically-generated content. The tipping point was, from my perspective, how the policy was unveiled. Per the Moderator Agreement, policies are supposed to be reviewed by moderators on the Moderator Team prior to being made public. Although the agreement doesn't say how long the review period is, a day of review that starts on a holiday in the US, Canada, UK, and other countries doesn't seem to be consistent with the spirit of the agreement. In addition, the post on the Moderator Team was a decree or edict and not an opportunity to give feedback. However, this is just one in a trend of announcing fundamental platform and policy changes without appropriate feedback.

Although I don't doubt that, across the network, there were a large number of accounts with few (or no) contributions suspended, this policy is far more forgiving than our policies to deal with spammers. I moderate two smaller sites on the network, where we had less than 10 accounts suspended for posting algorithmically-generated content. Only 1 had meaningful contributions previously. If they had posted spam, the majority of the accounts would have been destroyed, which would have also fed into anti-spam measures. If there was a human behind these accounts, there's a (small) possibility that they have learned a lesson and contributed in the future. However, my suspicion is that these accounts were created only to post generated content and there was minimal loss by suspending these accounts. If the problem was indeed the suspensions, then I know that I would have agreed to end the policy of immediately jumping to 30-day suspensions (which was something promoted by the staff), and I suspect other moderators would have as well.

Personally, it seems like leadership at the company doesn't understand where we're coming from or what we want. And that is the first fundamental step to take.

Comment: This is not just "not a good start". It's the opposite of what we're requiring. This only reinforces the strike.

Comment: "These unnecessary suspensions and their outsize impact on new users run counter to our mission and have a negative impact on our community." This is simply untrue. We are the community, and we are sending SE a message. They don't get to put words in our mouths. Accept the words we're giving, instead.

Comment: also, the CEO here is using private communications with the mods, that's just so completely wrong that I'm kind of amazed at it

Comment: Zoe (who was interviewed by Dev Class) claims that the 11% was accurate at the time, but the percentage on Stack Overflow in specific is much higher now: 15/27 (according to the [list of moderators on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators)) makes 55% of Stack Overflow elected moderators on strike.

Comment: "Usage of these tools correlated to a dramatic upswing in suspensions of users with little or no prior content contributions; " -- because both correlate to the rise of people posting ChatGPT spam. It's not rocket science. And correlation is not causation, obviously.

Comment: @E_net4isonstrike I didn't make a claim about 11% being accurate or not. Even if it's a small fraction of total moderators, it's _the most active moderators on the most active sites_. It's also some of the most active curators on the most active sites. It's going to be a huge strain to have these people not participating.

Comment: @ThomasOwens Sure, I wasn't implying that you stood by this percentage, just added some more context. By the way, network-wide it has already reached 14%.

Comment: An unfortunate comment but an unsurprising one. A company's natural reaction to a strike is to discount the threat. But there's a reason we're actually *doing* this and not just talking about it: Because the longer we hold out, the more they have to accept that those of us making a point here are a vital and difficult-to-replace part of the ecosystem.

Comment: @E_net4isonstrike Minor clarification: 11% was correct _network-wide_ at the time, but not on SO in particular. Note how the CEO fails to call it the Stack Exchange network, but says "Stack Overflow network" (not just Stack Overflow). If it's specifically SO, then yes, 11% is a blatant lie. SO (the site) has had >50% sign the open letter since at least yesterday. However, this morning, 11% network-wide would've  been approximately correct. It's currently at 14%+

Comment: On Academia.SE, the percentage of striking moderators is 100%. One of us already resigned due to the policy and the manner it was passed down. The policy is against academic ethics of attribution and honesty, and potentially dangerous to many of the askers on our site who are looking for professional guidance from humans with experience in Academia, as they confront conflicts that will determine the course of their careers.

Comment: "is something that has been discussed" My impression is that publicly not so much was discussed. For example see Makyen on [How can we determine whether an answer used ChatGPT?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421889/1536976) "The general question of how to detect these posts is something we've been avoiding publicly answering..." So basically a no comment. I would have liked to discuss it more.

Comment: From the details it looks as if the number of suspensions for posting AI generated content wasn't very large and every single case could be vetted carefully. This sounds good but is a bit in contrast with the warnings that AI generators would make it so easy for people to post such content. I would have expected an actually really large number of suspensions then. Maybe some stats about how many accounts were suspended for this (especially on SO) would be helpful.

Comment: @Trilarion A lot of the heuristics mods used, including our assessments of various detectors, was in mod only spaces to prevent people from being able to make the most minimal of changes to avoid detection. We don't discuss other moderator tools or techniques in public for similar reasons.

Comment: @Trilarion The amount of AI content was initially quite high, especially on SO; then, in consultation with staff, moderators took away the "carrot" for posting AI content: by deleting such content and suspending accounts when necessary, we made it so the value of posting AI-generated content here was low, which reduced submissions of that content. The same concept applies to all moderation: you aren't just acting on certain content, but discouraging it in the first place.

Comment: Really, it makes the CEO's claim that it is *suspensions for AI content* that have driven people away quite foolish, because the number affected is so small, while emphasizing the importance of moderating this content in the first place: it's what keeps the amount of AI content manageable.

Comment: the lack of transparency is alone enough to justify the strike anyway.

Comment: This statement now posted to MSE at "[Statement from SO: Moderator Action today](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389834/997587)". On the bright side, this is a step up from the silence on some other similar scenarios. Ex. [Why hasn't there been an official community announcement or blogpost about charging for usage of subscriber content in the training of LLMs?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388555/997587)

Comment: *"a day of review that starts on a holiday in the US, Canada, UK, and other countries doesn't seem to be consistent with the spirit of the agreement"* Especially when said day of "review" is after the policy is effective, which occurred simultaneously with it being given to moderators for said "review".   The moderator agreement requires a "preview for review"; this was not that, in either letter or spirit.

Answer (score 76):

### Power to the striking moderators! 100% support from us users.

[A Strike song for some inspiration...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vt5X8zrHiSM)

Having said that, I think the demands do not go nearly far enough. Like the opening post here said, this is much larger than the AI decision; it's about the entire relationship of the company to the community and network of sites.

I call on the striking moderators to demand the following:

- Formal declaration by **SE Inc. recognizing the Stack Exchange network as a public resource**, irrespective of its private ownership of servers, code, databases, copyrights, etc. And of SE Inc.'s relation to the network being foremost, though not exclusively, that of a *trustee*. (Yes, this should have legal ramifications.)
- Acceptance of a **community veto power on network policy changes**, the details of which the moderators should flesh out either as part of their demand or to be worked out in negotiations.
- A third-party **ombudsman for information disclosure** will be appointed, agreed upon by the company and the moderators (mechanism for such agreement to be worked out), who will have full and unrestrained access to all company documents and information, excluding employees' personal affairs and correspondence, and will have the authority and the obligation to disclose all such information which is deemed relevant to the network.
- **Accountability for SE Inc. management vis-à-vis the community** (collectively or individually)—a formal obligation, via SE Inc. company bylaws/charter or a binding agreement with the delegates of the moderators, to publicly answer, on Meta.SE, collective queries from the moderators, with full and complete answers (with exact mechanism to be worked out by moderators vis-a-vis management).

Whether these demands are a condition for ending your strike or not, that's entirely up to you. But I believe that is the kind of relationship change we need to see on this network (and I may not have even gone far enough).

Comment: All four of those are honestly really great ideas, but I don't have high confidence in *any* of them happening.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo: The first step towards achieving a goal is conceiving it. The second is putting it forward. The third is getting people to adopt it as a goal. Making it the demand of a strike may be the 6th or 7th step, but - at least I'm trying to help advance from one step to the next. Let the strikers decide how far they think they can go.

Comment: "But then we can't make _money_"

Comment: @OrangeDog: 1. "You make your money off of other things anyway, not the network itself: Ads, jobs, custom installations, etc." 2. "Really? Show us. Open your books and business plans. Otherwise it's just empty rhetoric." 3. "If you don't make enough money without hurting the network, spin it out into a not-for-profit entity and rearrange your business. If that non-proft needs money, it should not be much of a problem to fundraise from the community to maintain and develop the SE network."

Comment: Excellent suggestions, but humanity has a deadly tendency to follow those who should not lead, i.e., the masses believe CEOs are the appropriate decision-makers, when that role now is simply that of a parasite maximizing personal gain at the expense of the public and employees (loss of Titan submersible is glaring example). The history of evolution is necessarily bloody and our current insanity will not endure, but it is going to be painful for a while.

Comment: However noble your ideas might be, please never claim "100% support" on behalf of other people. You don't know it, and you don't represent all of "us users".

Comment: It's not "100% of users", it's "100% of the possible support".

Comment: The platform isn't yours, it has never been yours, and it won't be yours, even though you start identifying yourself as being a part of it. I actually find it very arrogant to demand ownership over something purely because you like it, so I guess the 100% claim isn't true. It's your choice to put that much time and heart into this. Don't depend on a platform over which you have no control, you could've known that from the start.

Comment: @Nearoo: The platform is one thing, and the network which rests upon it is another thing. Of course they are inter-dependent. As for the platform - that's a philosophical debate about the legitimacy of intellectual property etc., but it's irrelevant, since my my suggestions only regard the _network_ and its administration. The network, however, was created by the users (especially the moderators). It has been a collective social project which SE Inc. has facilitated, and to which it has contributed, but it is certainly not "theirs".

Comment: Have you checked out Codidact, btw? Seems like the way the Codidact Foundation is set up satisfies most if not all of what you ask for here.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: It's an interesting backup plan in case this platform explodes. But almost all of the information and users are here... also, this post was not a personal wish list, but a suggestion to a collective.

Answer (score 61):

**This is my personal opinion and not necessarily representative of all of the moderators, curators, and users on strike.**

The [first company response on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389834/572) was incredibly underwhelming.

> As you may be aware, a number of moderators (on Stack Overflow/across
> the network) have decided to stop engaging in several activities that
> they had taken on, including moderating content - in fact, almost all
> moderation tasks. The primary reason for this action is
> dissatisfaction with our position on detection tools regarding
> AI-generated content, and discontent with how that was rolled out.

This is an accurate assessment. Personally, I'm more discontented with *how* the position/policy was rolled out. Having an appropriate discussion with moderators and then the community, as it's laid out in the Moderator Agreement, would have been better, even if the result was the same policy.

> We ran an analysis and the ChatGPT detection tools have an alarmingly
> highly high rate of false positives, which is correlated to a dramatic
> upswing in suspensions of users with little or no prior content
> contributions.

As I, and other moderators, have said before, we do know that these tools aren't perfect. When the policy was handed down to moderators, there was an assertion of testing done on Stack Exchange data regarding the false positives in these detectors. However, no specific information was shared, although the moderators are expecting it to be provided in the near future. The tools were only a single tool used to detect algorithmically-generated post and [I'm not aware of any moderators who relied on a tool to tell them that a post was generated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389828/572).

When it comes to users with little or no prior content and posting content that is not permitted, suspension is letting them off easy. When garbage or spam is posted by accounts with no other valuable contributions, we destroy those accounts. In fact, there are destruction reasons for posting "spam or nonsense" without any other "positive participation" and for cases where the vast majority of content violates the terms of service. When we take these actions, not only is the account destroyed, but it feeds into

> People with original questions and answers were
> summarily suspended from participating on the platform. We stand by
> our decision to require that moderators stop using that tool. We will
> note that it appears to be very rare, however, for mods to use ONLY
> the ChatGPT detection tool, and frequently their own analyses were in
> use as well. We will continue to look for other, more reasonable tools
> and are committed to rapid testing of those tools and any suggested
> heuristic indicators.

There is a public admission that moderators used their own analysis. We also used other moderator tools and, in some cases, engaged with moderators from across the network, prior to taking action. Yet the response is to remove a valuable tool from the toolbox. Although there is a false positive rate, the analysis that was shared puts the false positive rate into what I would suspect would be a very tolerable number when combined with other tools, including other detectors.

> The moderators who are engaged in this action served this community
> collectively for many years on the platform. Personally, I consider a
> number of them friends, and anytime friendship is tested like this,
> it’s difficult. I would like to say to them clearly that I hope they
> know how much I, and the whole staff and community, appreciate their
> collective decades of service to this community, and I hope that we
> are able to come to a path forward. I regret that actions have
> progressed to this point. The Community Management team is evaluating
> the current situation and we’re working hard to stabilize things in
> the short term. We’ll be working collaboratively with the community on
> the long-term solution.

This is not the first time that we've been here. But lessons from the past don't appear to have been learned.

> I’ll be honest, the next few days and weeks might be a bit bumpy. Both
> sides share a deep and unchanged commitment to quality on this
> platform. Additionally, it’s important that we guarantee that anyone
> who has meaningful contributions to make has the opportunity to do so.
> As we have updates I and the team will be sharing them here.

I - and the moderators that I'm in touch with - are also very committed to the quality of content on the network. We do hope this resolves quickly, but at the same time, want the resolution that's best for our communities.

Comment: It is fascinating to watch this subset of the general civilization succumb to the ongoing disease process. Forget who said it, but laws don't control conduct so much as codify the moral convictions of the host culture, i.e., the problem here at SO/SE is that the basic problem of promoting high quality questions and answers (putting aside the usual sociology, see e.g. Freeman's Tyranny of Structurelessness) is made exponentially larger (volume) by use of ChatGPT and the like (suggest replace term "AI" with "ASS" analytical search software to reduce the eschatological panic of some).

Comment: It suddenly occurred to me yesterday that what is actually happening here is that the management of Stack Exchange/Overflow wants to provide so-called AI companies a venue to test and perfect (it is impossible to make something which is intrinsically not intelligent "perfect" but Family Feud shotgunning might provide higher percentage canned responses that are not obviously garbage) their product, with the ultimate goal of selling to Microsoft, Google or the like for that specific purpose, thereby generating a large payoff for management.

Comment: Didn't realize @leanne had already discussed likely plan by SO to produce income by cooperating with AI companies. See July 7, 2023 Stack Overflow CEO Prashanth Chandrasekar interview at VentureBeat https://venturebeat.com/ai/stack-overflow-ceo-teases-generative-ai-tools-addresses-
moderator-protest/ where this is pretty much confirmed. It appears Stack Exchange is dead already.

Answer (score 49):

Mainly focussing on the title, with the statement that *"Stack Overflow, Inc. cannot consistently ignore, mistreat, and malign its volunteers"*:

That's wrong. Of course they can. Obviously.

The most active sites already have been flooded with an unmanageable amount of low-quality content for years. Now, there's a new source of low-quality content. And... why exactly should they care about that?

They don't.

There will *always* be *new* people to join the site. Some of them will become volunteers who work off the crap-queues, for a few internet points and badges (Gamification 101). Some of them will become moderators, because ... oh, what a privilege and honor. Some of them will be disappointed with the increasing workload, the decreasing quality, and the ... $%!$§ ... behavior of the company. Some of them will complain. Some of them will leave. Some of them may initiate a strike *shrugs* - that's just noise. New users will come. New volunteers will come. New moderators will come.

They don't care.

I'm aware that this does not sound constructive. But I think that it is **important** to know that the company does not care about you **at all**. People who joined after the previous management debacles may not be aware of that. They may have joined with the same idealism and drive for altruism that I had ~10 years ago. And they should be prepared to be deeply, deeply disappointed.

They will sit that strike out.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the intent was more like "we (the signees) are not going to tolerate this treatment"- not literally "you can't treat us like this"

Comment: @starball Taking that statement literally was a dramaturgic device. They are either going to "tolerate" this treatment, or be replaced by others. The company can do whatever it wants. They may see the public _announcement_ of the strike as a minor nuisance, because now, they have to wait for the dust to settle and open a fresh can of apologies and promises. But they don't _really_ care about the people who are striking.

Comment: What you fail to acknowledge with this overly cynical take is that moderators/curators striking means that there is the potential for unchecked abuse on the site, which is even worse than spam. And abuse often doesn't surface with red flags that employees can go and check every once in a while. Delaying handling those situations can have real repercussions on the people involved (racism, harassment, bullying, etc.). Once it spreads the perception that the platform is unsafe, it's game over.

Comment: One thing that I can't understand right now. Let's imagine that the strike becomes effective and SE answers "our" demands. Who will fix the whole mess the day after?

Comment: "We hear you, from now on we will *inconsistently and capriciously* ignore, mistreat, and malign volunteers"

Comment: Totally agree, the company doesn't care. And I'm afraid that they will do exactly what I [commented here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1300383)

Comment: @blackgreenonstrike I acknowledge that insofar that I considered to bring up another point: Who would even _notice_ this strike if it wasn't announced publicly? Out of the ~5.5m daily visitors of SO, how many of them require moderation action, and notice when the action is not performed? An random (but high) guess of 1% would still mean that they have "99% customer satisfaction"... Yes, it may sound like "cynicism", but that may just be an expression of my _disappointment_, based on actual _observations_ that I made here in the past ~10 years. They. Don't. Care.

Comment: @blackgreenonstrike I don't think he meant that. I read this post as a quite realistic claim: even if every current moderator was to resign now, there is plenty of other users that are ready to take their place either because they don't have yet realized what the situation is or because they don't care. So the company will in a way always be able to find someone who will "polish the turds" to use shog9 old words. This seem to be tangential to my post [here](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/a/3430/7090)

Comment: The company doesn't really care - it's not a human being. But you can negotiate with it. It's not like it's not dependent on the mods or existing community. Sure it could try to find new mods and new users, but that is risky by itself and may fail. The striking mods however, must be prepared to walk away if necessary (not sure if they really are). That's the situation, in a nutshell.

Comment: @SPArcheon perhaps you are correct, and the cynical part of me somewhat agrees with that idea, but the other part doesn’t. I wouldn’t be striking if I thought the company doesn’t care as much as painted in this answer. Although… I probably would strike anyway because even if they don’t care, I do.

Comment: @Trilarion You've been involved in Meta so long that I'm surprised to see that optimism. SE does not really need a "community" (roughly: "a group that shares goals and values"). It needs _visitors_ and _activity_. I also don't see any risk in replacing mods with new ones. Each new generation will have the choice to swallow the poor treatment, or leave (and ... people will (have to and be willing to) swallow _a lot_). So imagine the striking mods went away now (and I share your doubts about that): What then? New ones will be elected, and stoically moderate auto-generated content...

Comment: @blackgreenonstrike You mentioned your "cynical" part and the "other" - what *is* this "other part"? (I could ask whether that other part is "naive" or "idealistic", but ... my _cynical_ part would say that these are not necessarily different things ;-)). But seriously: You've been here (on Meta) for 2 years. You replaced a mod who left after the 2019 debacle. That mod replaced one who left after 2015. And if you leave, you will be replaced, by someone who doesn't complain as much as you. (I'm playing <strike>devil's</strike> SE's advocate here, I hope that's obvious...).

Comment: @Marco13 I guess I'm naturally optimistic. I just don't want to believe yet that the company pulls an Elon Musk and fires everyone who isn't agreeing with them. But it may happen if course. Having a team of highly efficient mods is valuable, but maybe not that much.

Comment: Of course they don't care about the users/mods, but not caring about the quality of content (which they don't rn) is not a sustainable practice for such a website. Threatening to make the quality even worse (which is what the strike essentially does) is probably the only way the moderators (and users) have to pressure any change.

Comment: @liakoyras People will do websearches, find a few bad Q/As, and maybe one of the answers solves their issue, and maybe not. Where do moderation or the strike come into play here? Maybe someone flags a comment, and the flag is not handled, but that affects only people who _care_ about stuff like that, and is totally unrelated to "(technical) quality". When "the community" is defined as "people who strive for quality", and SE does not care about quality, then it does not care about the community. (Sure, that's oversimplified, but ... too little space for too many management failures here)

Comment: Maybe I should have phrased it as "ought to care". I took the strike as a taste of what the sites would be without moderation (and by that I don't only mean the actual mods, a lot of other active users participate too). If the quality falls, users will stop clicking (as I already do with Quora for example). The quality is based upon the best efforts of the community, whether through QA or moderation. I think that long term, lowering of the quality will be bad for their business, but only time will tell.

Comment: @blackgreenonstrike: "What you fail to acknowledge with this overly cynical take is that moderators/curators striking means that there is the potential for unchecked abuse on the site". Any strike against any organization will always hamper the organization's ability to function while the strike is in effect. This is why striking can be effective at motivating organizations to reconsider their policies. And it's no reason to prohibit, discourage, or avoid strikes.

Comment: @HippoMan The strike may negatively affect users, e.g. users who flag an insulting comment that is then not removed - i.e. the users who **care**. That's perfectly in line with what I said. But it differs from your view of the strike: The strike does not affect _the company or its operation_  from a purely economic perspective. They have same click counts (if not more). The same ads being served. SE is an oil tanker on the Atlantic, and will keep heading straight towards its goal, even with the crew on strike. (Sure, it will crash, eventually, but ... that's the point of that metaphor...)

Comment: I stopped being active between the pronouns brain washing and "moderating bad English is harmful" witch hunts...IMO the only SE goal is amassing visitor numbers to show to investors, without worrying they are real numbers, or for the quality, or for we not being all 20s something USA residents. SE suffers from the "too big to fail" syndrome.  +1 vote

Answer (score 42):

> Reveal to the community the internal AI policy given directly to moderators. The fact that you have made one point in private, and one in public, which differ so significantly has put the moderators in an impossible situation, and made them targets for being accused of being unreasonable, and exaggerating the effect of the new policy. Stack Exchange, Inc. has done the moderators harm by the way this was handled. The company needs to admit to their mistake and be open about this.

[I agree](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389810/1135948) that it would absolutely be in the community's interests to be able to read this secret policy. It is completely unreasonable for us to be subject to new rules which can't even be said in public.

If Stack Exchange, Inc. won't allow the policy to be published here, there are [other](https://www.theregister.com/Profile/contact/) [venues](https://www.theverge.com/a/tip-us-secure-contact-email) [which](https://arstechnica.com/news-tips/) [might](https://techcrunch.com/got-a-tip/) [consider](https://www.vice.com/en/article/a37pp4/how-to-securely-contact-motherboard) [publishing](https://gizmodo.com/how-to-tip-gizmodo-1843880833) [it](https://www.zdnet.com/tip-us-off/). (These outlets have written about Stack Overflow's policy on AI content before, so they might run further stories on the same topic.)

To me, it seems inevitable that the secret policy will become available one way or another, so it's just better for everyone if Stack Exchange, Inc. publishes it themselves.

Comment: Moderators tend to take our obligations to protect moderator-only information seriously. We recognize that there are aspects of the policy shared with moderators that should not be shared with the public. I believe most of us think that the company should be the one to disclose their policy, since it is their policy. But revoking the policy and following the agreement to discuss policies before rolling them out would be the preference.

Comment: @ThomasOwens I agree, the company should disclose the policy. My answer here is an argument for why it is in their interests to do so ─ i.e. it will get disclosed sooner or later anyway, if they don't publish it then someone else will.

Comment: It reads like you're suggesting that a moderator leak the full version of the private policy to the press. Meta is where public policies are posted, with links from the private version to the public version as well as with links from the Help Center to the public Meta posts.

Comment: @ThomasOwens I haven't told anyone to leak anything. I've stated that I believe the community has an interest in seeing the policy (an opinion you haven't disagreed with), that it could be leaked (a statement of fact which I presume you don't dispute), and that I believe it's inevitable it will be leaked if it's not posted officially (a judgement which perhaps you disagree with, but you haven't persuaded me that it's not inevitable).

Comment: You mention about protecting moderator-only information, but information itself can't be harmed and doesn't need protecting; it is people's interests in that information which can be harmed and may need protecting. If we accept that the community has an interest in seeing this information, then whose interests are protected by it remaining private? The fact that the strike is occurring at all shows that many moderators are not specifically motivated to protect Stack Exchange, Inc.'s interests. If there is any information mixed in with the policy which it would harm someone else's interests ...

Comment: ... if it were disclosed, then like you I trust that that information won't be leaked, because as you say, moderators take their obligation to protect private information (i.e. protect people's privacy) seriously.

Comment: there is just one issue: the confusion works in their favor. The users only see the part of the picture while only the moderators see the full version. Considering that the moderators themselves had to ask the company to avoid misrepresenting the issue in articles published by other sites, it looks like this is intentional. That way, at least a small part of users will think that the mods are acting unreasonable because all they see is a policy that does not contain any of the bigger issues shared only in private.

Answer (score 38):

This is peripheral to the question, but pertinent:

I'm perplexed as to why the company is seeking to destroy itself in this manner.
While a useful amount of AI output is reasonably accurate and useful, a significant portion is either very misleading or entirely fabricated.

ChatGPT will:

- Produce totally fake references,
- Produce wholly non-existent web links.
- Make comments which, when challenged, it will disclaim and say something entirely different.
- In some cases contradict itself in the same answer.

The only way to deal with these issues is to either have an expert knowledge greater than the level in the answer, or to use it only as a source for cross referencing.

- **By allowing essentially uncontrolled use the
  company will destroy the integrity of its core asset.**

**A relevant example:**  I am not a [Quora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quora) member, but I read a significant number of their answers in my (relatively wide) areas of interest. I have been surprised to see some Quora members, obviously using ChatGPT for essentially their whole answers, producing many factually incorrect and hardly relevant answers, but receiving numerous upvotes from other members.

While Quora still contains a very large percentage of genuine and highly useful human-generated answers, it is obvious that they have not chosen to actively oppose the posting of complete rubbish to their site. The likely outcome seems clear.
Why [Stack Exchange inc](https://wiki2.org/en/Stack_Exchange) would wish to follow the same path is puzzling.

---

**Added:**

The company may be inadvertently "throwing the baby out with the bathwater".
The proposed use of AI to improve asked questions has SOME prospect of being useful.

Experienced users can ignore the advice (as long as it is only advice) and many beginners would benefit from good advice.

Worst case, it may make questions worse in some cases (but possibly not too many) and bad questions can be and presently are treated badly.   This would be a negative for newcomers, but it could be ameliorated by thoughtful community action if members are prepared to actively help newcomers. Based on present practices, this seems unlikely; I perceive the site and the majority of member actions creating a substantial barrier for new members. Improving this is hard.

Overall, AI may quite possibly improve questions on average.
This impression may affect the company's perception of AI answer improvement, which is far less likely to be net-positive overall.

One area where I have reservations is the suggested use of AI generated code to improve questions. This is very much a "double edged sword" as AI code is often good, but may contain subtle errors leading to 'rubbish out'. If new user code related questions suddenly sprout AI-generated code examples, the quality would need to be extremely high on average to not produce negative reactions overall from the community.

Comment: re: "_By allowing essentially uncontrolled use the company will destroy the integrity of its core asset._" - sadly and bafflingly, they seem to already be aware of this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy

Comment: Because SE is no longer close to the users in any realistic sense, the layers of narcissistic management that march to the latest admin fad; ESG gibberish, is complete with the takeover by Prosus. This may end badly. Hard to predict.

Comment: @starball just because they agreed with the community to allow moderators to implement the ban (initially) and to publish that policy document, doesn't mean they've actually considered the implications of the underlying argument, nor that they agree.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I've added a comment re AI -improved questions.  It is pssible that they see the genuine advantages in that area and are blinding themselves to the **fact** that Ai generted answers are net-negative for quality except when vetted expertly.

Comment: AI is a useful tool in the hands of someone willing to invest some time to understand it and its limitations. For example, I could it to generate example sentences to illustrate a particular usage for my ELL answers. It is not useful (yet) as a general tool the way SE is experimenting with it. It requires a LOT of work to get a model that encodes a good post in SE terms. Right now, it's adding "Thanks in advance" type signatures and other undesired but prevalent content. There are many highly scored posts on SO that are not good exemplars for new users.

Comment: @ColleenV Fundamentally, this style of generative AI will never be able to improve content by being trained on the overall corpus of the existing content. By design, it will generate output that mimics what is already there. The public ChatGPT has, to my understanding, already been fed with the entirety of SO (as of somewhere in 2021?) among many other sources. And as you say, such a model cannot necessarily be re-trained by feeding it a subset of SO selected by any simple heuristic (such as post score). It would need a fundamentally different kind of AI to filter the training data.

Comment: And even then, these tools are fundamentally unsuited for tasks that require actual programming-like problem solving - just as Copilot cannot write your program for you (if it could, it would have already taken over the world by now, or at least eliminated the overwhelming majority of existing programming jobs).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I've said it before--we haven't made the breakthrough that leads to the scary kind of AI capable of self improvement (yet). The generative stuff can be a great tool, but people underestimate the amount of human labor it takes to get it there. [AI Is a Lot of Work](https://www.theverge.com/features/23764584/ai-artificial-intelligence-data-notation-labor-scale-surge-remotasks-openai-chatbots) (Article from The Verge) I don't think people understand how much subsistence wage labor these systems are built upon.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel   I wanted to load photos to Facebook so that they appeared in the album in date order. I can do that manually by uploading them one at a time. I asked CHATGPT 3.5 how to do this. I described the task clearly, told it what works and what the issues were otherwise. It provided a Python program plus links to two necessary downloads from elsewhere. I have not yet tried it but it looks sound. I've never used Python.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon And when running that code, it may import packages made by blackhats. https://twitter.com/llm_sec/status/1667573374426701824 (Found via Jon Ericson's tweets).

Comment: @RussellMcMahon "I have not yet tried it but it looks sound. I've never used Python." - yes; **that's the exact problem**. ChatGPT has never *used* Python either, and *doesn't actually have any idea* whether the code is sound, no matter how strongly it might "profess confidence" (generate text that represents such claims) in the code. It doesn't *have ideas* at all. It *only* has an extremely sophisticated model of what words are likely to follow what other words, taking a rather large amount of context into account, using much more sophisticated algorithms than older attempts at AI.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel  Indeed. It may not work. BUT I started programming in FORTRAN in 1969, and in machine code (not assembler) on a NatSemi SC/MP microprocessor in 1976,. I often dwelt in the darkness of embedded systems and assembler (!!!) (6800, 8080, Z80, 6502, AVR, PIC, ... but various other languages and systems have happened along the way. I'm 72 :-). The code and the  added packages seemed sound and logical. I've never used Python, but reading the code it makes sense. It MAY have faults I've missed. tbd.

Comment: @S.L.Barthsupportsmodstrike  Yes. I'd not seen that done, but it's obvious in retrospect. || In my example I've looked at the pckages suggested and am happy that they are legitimate. (My happiness may or may not correlate well with rality :-) ).

Comment: I agree, @KarlKnechtel. Another of many examples: I asked ChatGPT how many times I need to take the square root of an an adult's age before the result is less than 1. ChatGPT replied that as long as the age is a positive integer, only two square roots will be needed to yield an answer less than one. And I asked the same question again, and this time, I got of lot of totally incorrect gibberish about logarithms. Relying on a tool like ChatGPT to provide correct, useful, reliable answers to ***anything*** is an exercise in folly.

Comment: @HippoMan  Used with due diligence CGPT is a superb and useful tool. As a metaphor, it's like a double ended Katana with a mid grip and no hand guards. You can cut yourself as easily as your opponent without training and consant care.  Or a pair of Nunchuks in other than expert hands :-).

Comment: @RussellMcMahon: If by "Used with due diligence" you mean something like, "There are lots of things that ChatGPT should absolutely not be used for, and one should use due diligence to make sure that the software is never utilized for any of those purposes," then I would agree with you. In addition to not attempting to use it to try to solve math problems, other things which ChatGPT should absolutely not be used for are to try to distinguish fact from fantasy, and to try to distinguish truth from falsehood.

Comment: @HippoMan ChatGPT is simply a tool, mostly a search tool. You have to check all the output but the suggestions by it can be helpful. Chat GPT helped me. I'm using it. I'm just not writing my contributions to the network with it. But at some point I can imagine that it will help me, but I will still check everything from it

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution: yes, ChatGPT can be useful, but it has no way of filtering out false information from its search results. Relying on ChatGPT or other LLM-based tools to verify the integrity of other text is a mis-use of those kinds of tools, due to the lack of safeguards against false positives and false negatives.

Answer (score 31):

I wrote [a user style](https://stackapps.com/questions/9747/user-style-for-mod-strike) to hide the review queue, downvote, VTC, VTD, delete, undelete, and flag buttons/links.

Answer (score 19):

The purpose of this answer is to provide an indication of the financial motivation for SE's decisions. In all humility I would suggest that one cannot assign motive for any particular actions without following the money. In that vein, a good starting point may be to see who the investors in SE were in the latest Series D startup financial round. A Series D startup is generally either one which has not achieved its objectives in rounds A, B and C, or one that is designed to prepare a company for going public. Said information is available [crunchbase's stack-exchange](https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/stack-exchange/company_financials) financial base. These include
[image]
and can be followed up for further investigation by following the link above and links to those investors.
More complete information is on [pitchbook SO](https://pitchbook.com/profiles/company/51667-48#signals).

It may have made more sense to offer SE's users and moderators the ability to invest in SE in a funding round than to do so seeking investment from those with little or no understanding of what they purchased, and who come with intellectual baggage or conflicted interests and may or may not wish to dismantle SE or transform it to be unrecognizable. Such is the behaviour of the *nouveau riche* who for good reason are oft regarded as uncouth.

Rather than lamenting an opportunity lost, perhaps investigation of a means of having SE's users buy out SE should be explored, as management currently is inept enough that that may be its most realistic option.

Unfortunately SO (and SE) was bought out by [Prosus](https://www.techradar.com/news/stack-overflow-snapped-up-by-prosus-in-billion-dollar-deal) for $1.8 billion. As Prosus is an ESG activist investment firm, it has the power to distort market forces by propagandizing, censoring, and proselytizing Neo-Marxist ideation. For example, it is a major shareholder in Tencent, a Chinese information firm.

**Edit** BTW, I'm poisoned, I have almost completely stopped reviewing, posting, voting, etc. Stuff like this doesn't help.

Comment: Why buy them out, when we ourselves are the primary asset?

Comment: @kaya3-supportthestrike To manage that asset properly, i.e., it would better insure the corporate pecuniary interests are a positive sum game. A bit like owning a home rather than squatting in an abandoned one.

Comment: *perhaps investigation of a means of having SE's users buy out SE should be explored* => sounds good in theory, in practice you'd never be able to agree on who gets to control the website.

Comment: @JonathanReez There are good management styles out there, but no perfect ones anywhere. What is needed is a board that includes influential users, not social influencers.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377908/introduce-an-optional-se-gold-subscription-so-that-we-can-support-se-directly

Comment: Also I think at this point - they all got bought out by prosus? And we don't have a few billion dollars sitting around

Comment: @JourneymanGeek If so, we are toast, as Prosus is appears to be brain dead.

Comment: @Carl can you point out to an example of at least one organization with 1m+ users/customers which fits your criteria? I can't think of a single example - i.e. Wikipedia has had plenty of controversy over how they're wasting their money on non profits instead of being laser focused on maintaining the site.

Comment: @JonathanReez I could, but you are correct that anti-ESG activity is in its infancy. I predict it will grow as more investors (like me) direct their portfolios away from unprofitable ESG firms.

Comment: By "ESG" do you mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environmental,_social,_and_corporate_governance ?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Indeed. Long story short, the management class produces harebrained schemes in this the ["third" stage](https://hbr.org/2014/07/managements-three-eras-a-brief-history) called *empathy* of the development of capitalist management. So called "empathy" is merely Neo-Marxist jargon for dialectic materialism, which is, in effect, the elimination of concepts dangerous to the ruling state, the rewrite of definitions of words to prevent thought, the propagation of really stupid ideas favorable to the state and the like as outlined in "1984" by George Orwell.

Comment: ESG = [Environmental, social, and corporate governance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environmental,_social,_and_corporate_governance). ... *"also known as environmental, social, governance, is a business framework for considering environmental issues and social issues in the context of corporate governance. It is designed to be embedded into an organization's strategy that considers the needs and ways in which to generate value for all organizational stakeholders (such as employees, customers, suppliers, and financiers)."*

Comment: Re *"Prosus is an ESG activist investment firm"*: Who says that? Are you sure they are not solely driven by quarterly results?

Comment: If they were, how is it connected to the current crisis? It sounds more like an opportunity to air a particular political view.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum Read their website, they say it themselves. Their activist policies are reflected here. This isn’t just about the new AI policy, it comes with a portfolio of other activist policies, e.g., climate change, pronoun usage, Covid-19 propaganda, and lately AI. To turn this around and say that it is I who is airing a particular political view is to ignore the fact that you are being told what you are allowed to think for a slew of issues. I didn't choose the issues, but I will be dammed if I will ignore them all with the exception of one of them that you object to.

Comment: "It may have made more sense to offer SE's users and moderators the ability to invest in SE in a funding round" - this has never worked. Not once, and it never will work. A single one of these giant investment companies has more money than all the users and moderators put together. They control us, just like a king controls his peasants.

Comment: @user253751 Ever hear of the 80-20 rule? Some of the users might just have $1.8 billion just lying around, not that they would tell us. It is true that ESG has $30 trillion behind it. It won't last longer than Hitler's fascism or Stalin's communism. Bad ideas tend not to have staying power.

Comment: Do you truly believe the SE users will invest in SE under the current circumstances ? Why would I invest my money in SE after seeing a lot of spam posts and ChatGPT posts ?

Comment: @Nobody The decision to invest would be contingent upon the opportunity to invest, and right now, there is none. As to who does what when, investors make money sometime after they actually do invest. If the current management runs the company into the ground by making stupid decisions, an opportunity might arise to purchase it inexpensively and turn it around.

Comment: @Carl "_If the current management runs the company into the ground by making stupid decisions_" I don't think it's "If". They are making stupid decisions. My primary site is Academia.SE, we have many more spam posts and ChatGPT posts than ever.

Comment: @Carl I used to work for a big company that was near bankruptcy. It was merged into an even bigger company. Before the merger, the management worked very hard to increase the value of the company so they made money by converting their stocks. But, I am not seeing SO/SE management is trying to increase the value of the company. Instead, they are decreasing the value. What they are doing doesn't make sense to me at all.

Comment: @Nobody They are acting _exactly_ like countless companies did around the IT hype early 2000s. They have no goals or long term strategies, just mindlessly chasing a buzzword hype. The only thing of substance is to repeat the buzzword as much as possible - that's the entirely business model. It's just castles made of sand with a label on top of it, just switch the label from "IT" to "AI" or any other fashionable buzzword. All such companies sooner or later violently crash into bankruptcy and the investors lose all their money. Why would they do it? Because scamming is as old as mankind itself.

Comment: As for buying SE, the company has zero value to the community. All content is open license. A non-profit, open source community like [Codidact](https://codidact.com/) can legally just pull the data from SE just fine, as long as there is attribution to the original author. Some sites like https://writing.codidact.com did just that - exported the entire content from https://writing.stackexchange.com/ and started anew. Why pay $1.8 billion when you can have it for free. This was a failsafe that Atwood/Spolsky made on purpose, in case SO would turn into complete a**hats in the future.

Comment: @Nobody Yes, the latest craze is ESG. It is like dot com, and will finish badly. ESG is an emperor without cloths with citizens like Chicken Little, who is encouraged to repeat that "The sky is falling."

Comment: @Nobody It can be compared to Reddit, which is destroying the foundation of the site's value, in the hope that they'll be able to sell it before the top floors collapse, and they'll be able to misrepresent the operating expenses to the person they sell it to, because there will be no foundations.

Comment: @Lundin Wow. So without the good will of its users, SO (SE) is essentially worthless. It wouldn't take much money to start over with a better administration. I've seen that idea presented here before with the Monica Cellio incident. If I had to guess, that may happen this time, people are tired of fighting nonsense.

Comment: @Nobody One can compare SO with Vice that was, at one point, evaluated at $5.7 billion. Vice was just [bought out of bankruptcy for $222 million](https://www.livemint.com/companies/news/bankrupt-vice-media-to-be-acquired-by-fortress-investment-group-in-a-222-million-deal-11687485762423.html) or 3.9% of what was once claimed.

Comment: What do you mean by "poisoned"?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Colloquial expression meaning fed up, sated, had one's fill, etc.

Comment: @Carl "Start over"---that seems to be the only way to recreate the real Stack Exchange/Stack Overflow. Only this time let there be a binding open source-like constitution of sorts to assure that the new platform cannot be sold, but must remain open source, dedicated to public good, knowledge.

Comment: @DaltonBentley Not geared toward user "numbers" facilitating drive trough users spam.

Comment: @DaltonBentley What is not geared? This site, this question, this post, what?

Comment: @Carl I think Rui intended to say he agreed that we must recreate the real Stack Exchange/Stack Overflow and that goals should include not operating the site(s) simply to achieve large numbers of users ("drive-through spam" would result).

Comment: @DaltonBentley Humm. As it turns out, negative opinions are less reliable than positive ones. Voting for something usually means some deliberation has occurred. Voting against something does not require weighing the issues. For example, I am in favor of climate change, which means that I have actually thought about it. Most people think "CO2 is bad," because they have been told that, but how many people actually understand what climate is on a geologic and evolutionary time scale, or how atmospheric pressure has changed with time, or the geologic carbon cycle?

Answer (score 7):

As someone who has been working on programing and data analysis on computers since 1981, I am **very concerned** about allowing people to submit answers that **are not** a product of their own minds but a product of an **artificial intelligence** that has simply collected a series individual 'facts', made available by persons unknown, which leads to a conclusion which may (or may not) be plausible.

The same applies to an **artificial intelligence** (AI) tools checking whether artificial intelligence has created an answer.

That the moderators are **not using** these tools is, to me at least, obvious, based on their actions that I have observed in the last 6 months.

I myself have flagged/voted many answers that due the style of writing, lack of sources and often **very weird** constellations of 'facts' making it obvious to me who has the required background knowledge in the topic of the question.

The last 2 weeks the *user Serg Z*

- [2023-07-22: User spamming chatbot answers - Mathematics Meta Stack Exchange](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35868/user-spamming-chatbot-answers)

on [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/tour) and [History](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour) Stack Exchange, has flooded many existing questions with junk answers.

How should a later reader determine which answer is based on knowledge and facts and which are simply a collection of random facts pasted together by a AI and submitted by a user **as if it was their answer**?

---

Below is a email I sent to three friends today.

- a Professor of Philosophy from Vancouver, Canada

  - who is sympathetic to the idea of a central source of knowledge
- a US programmer since the mid 1960's for supply automation in the car industry and later debit bookings
- the Italian author of a well known PC based Spatial software who I have worked with for many years

I have added this mainly for the benefit of the *business leadership of Stack Exchange, Inc.* so that can, hopefully, better understand from the viewpoint of a data analysis on computers of many decades that the AI policy should be to treat such answers as a form of **plagiarism** (and therefore be deleted), since the answer is not a product of the author that submitted the answer.

The ChatGPT experience was from December 2022, where it became clear that the system (at least then) was designed to give an answer **at all costs** not caring if the result was nonsense or not. This is **copy and paste knowledge** at its worst.

---

I was taught that one 'had to learn how to learn'.

One lesson was that one had to have enough background knowledge to determine if any found/returned result was plausible (part of the 'learning' process).

Next, check the sources from preferably multiple -independent- reliable sources.

Finally assume that any result might not be conclusive and that multiple possibilities may exist (often dependent on certain situations).

In 1981, long before the first [MS-DOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS) for PC's were available here, the first lesson in the programming course was: A program will always be as stupid as the person that programmed it (you can't program a bookkeeping program if you know nothing about bookkeeping). Lesson #2: the main difference between a stupid program and a stupid person is that the stupid program is more capable in making more mistakes faster.

---

Tell this to some people today and you can see the question in their eyes: 'From what alternative universe (far, far, away) does this person come from?'.

This is what is meant with 'a critical lack of tech skills' in the article below.

> In the report the tech giant [Google] also highlights what it calls "a critical lack of tech skills in the UK", which - if unaddressed - will "remain a stubborn barrier to equitable nation-wide growth, especially as demand for AI and other tech expertise soars".

- [2023-07-28: BBC News - Google: Don't trust what our chatbot Bard tells you](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-66303877)

A few years ago, I saw a quote:

> With the internet making information available to everyone will make them smarter
>
> - well, we got that one wrong didn't we?

As far as I am concerned, for the likes of ChatGPT and Bard, the first two lessons from 1981 still apply.

---

On History Stack Exchange forum there was a question about a ChatGPT result that the person couldn't make sense of:

- [2022-12-25: Was there a Moresnet Conference of 1867?](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/70601/38607)

So I tried the ChatGPT system for the first (and only) time to see if I could figure out how ChatGPT came to the result that the OP of the question reported.

My conclusion was that ChatGPT was designed never to say 'I don't know' or 'insufficient results to come to a (sane) conclusion'.

It collected 3 facts that were true for a 3 month period in 1867:

- 1815-12: Dutch and Prussian representatives created Neutral Moresnet

  - since 1830 Belgium instead of the Netherlands
  - existed until 1914
- 1867-04/06 : International Monetary Conference of 1867 in Paris (Latin Monetary Union)
- 1867-03-23 / 1867-05-11 Luxembourg Crisis

Thus the 'Moresnet Conference of 1867' (with the participation of The Netherlands, Prussia and Luxembourg - who never belonged to the Latin Monetary Union - and Luxembourg that had nothing to do with Neutral Moresnet) was simply 'created' as a fact, with no supporting sources, hoping that nobody would notice that the answer is nonsense.

For the gullible, ChatGPT and Co. are a dangerous source of information.

Comment: There's a lot in this answer, but a lot of it is also not a comment on the strike. I think this answer is better suited to a question that discusses the ban on LLM content... While I agree with the answer, it does not seem to answer this question.

Comment: @Cerbrus The simple non acceptance by the *Stack Exchange, Inc.* that AI generated answers is **plagiarism** seems to me to be a major, justified, cause of the strike. That the moderators **don't** use (as implied) the AI tools, with the reason why, is also stated.

Comment: Yes, in the first 3 paragraphs... But the rest of the answer? It kinda lacks focus. Again, I agree with your points, I just think this is not quite the place.

Comment: @Cerbrus As stated it was mainly for the benefit for *Stack Exchange, Inc.* to assist in understanding why the moderators and some users are reacting this way. Understanding the reason why, often helps in resolving a problem. That was my intension of adding what I actually wrote to others this morning.

Comment: "*For the gullible, ChatGPT and Co. are a dangerous source of information.*" -> did you mean "***mis**information*"? :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your informative answer. It was a pleasure to read.

Comment: @OldPadawan No, for them it is considered a source of information. When rephrased (What major conference took place in 1867?) correct results were returned. But adding 'Neutral Moresnet' to the question an incorrect result was returned. Those familiar with the events (or do cross checking as the OP did) recognise this. But some peaple don't, assuming (incorrectly) that only correct information is returned. The lack of sources makes it more difficult. ...

Comment: @OldPadawan Looking at [International Monetary Conference of 1867](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Monetary_Conference#First_conference), shows quickly that it took place in Paris and not in Moresnet as claimed. That is the danger in my mind, since it makes it more difficult to check if the result is plausible.

Comment: @MarkJohnson, LLMs aren't deliberately designed to not say "I don't know".  Rather, the inability to say "I don't know" is an unavoidable consequence of how they work: LLMs provide the text that, based on the training data, is most likely to follow the input.  The only way to get an "I don't know" out of one is to provide it with a list of things that it doesn't know.

Comment: @Mark More the reason that LLM (Logic Learning Machine) should not be the source for answers based on knowlage. If it cannot state either: 'Yes,an answer is possible ' or 'No, an reliable answer is not possible' then it is neither logical nor intelligent.

Comment: That's a weird backronym. Generally, LLM stands for Large Language Model.

Comment: @tripleee There are many usages of [LLM - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLM) as an abbreviation. That is why it should be written out when first used.

Comment: If you are discussing ChatGPT in particular, I think it's fair to assume that you should be familiar with the central terminology, especially as this meaning of the abbreviation LLM has become almost a household word in recent months.

Comment: ChatGPT *can* be useful, just not for anything factual (or at least it must be thoroughly checked). For instance, to come up with input for a regular web search.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum When thoroughly checked (with possible adaptions/corrections/additions) then it becomes a product of their own mind. When it is **blindly copied and pasted** and posted as if it is their own product, then it is **plagiarism**. The problem is that many of these 'authors' don't have the faintest idea (or worse care) if 'their' answer is factualy correct or a chapter of history from alternative-reality-1527 but submit it anyway to gain reputations. That is the problem in my mind.

Answer (score 1):

If I visit the [open letter](https://openletter.mousetail.nl/) website it states that the strike is finally over:

[image]

I want to know if this is an official statement or not.

Thanks beforehand.

Comment: You may want to read over the answers/comments on [Moderation strike: Results of negotiations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391847/moderation-strike-results-of-negotiations)

Comment: To recap, it is "official" as far as the organizer of the open letter is concerned. The strike was not tightly coordinated or controlled, so there will be different groups of users with different criteria for when exactly to resume moderation activities. Some are probably waiting to see if the promises and concessions made my the company are in fact more than just words; and some will probably never return.

Comment: See also [What do you feel like is still missing to end the strike?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391925/what-do-you-feel-like-is-still-missing-to-end-the-strike)

Answer (score -29):

### It would make sense for a company promoting and selling new technology to buy up a company selling old technology and then mothball its old-technology operations.

Meanwhile it would make sense for a company promoting and selling old technology to get with it and maximise its selling price with the above in mind.

"Artificial intelligence" is about solving issues - perhaps even issues you didn't know existed - by running computer programs. OpenAI is a leader in the field.

SE/SO is the world's leading site featuring expert questions and answers that are written by human intelligences. Go figure.

*Edit: it seems from comments that Prosus, the company that already owns SO/SE, already knows a fair bit about AI, so perhaps SO/SE is not about to be sold. As user [@leanne writes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389811/moderation-strike-stack-overflow-inc-cannot-consistently-ignore-mistreat-an/389994#389994), it seems the writing is on the wall. Online expert question and answer provision based on human intelligence is about to get cut back drastically.*

*Another edit: OK, downvoters, the decision is nothing to do with profit and AI-isation but derives merely from ignorance at the top of the company of what the company's unpaid volunteers know. Seriously how likely does that sound?

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to say here. Maybe some more clarity is needed.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're saying here ─ are you claiming that SE, Inc. has been bought by an AI company who is now intentionally running into the ground? Or that it is pre-emptively running itself into the ground in order to make itself more appealing to be bought by an AI company? This doesn't really make sense, because if SE, Inc. will run itself into the ground then there's no need for an AI company to buy it in order to do that.

Comment: Go figure what?

Comment: Moderators are saying they deal with a very large number of what they have concluded to be AI-generated answers. Instruct them not to be so hard on such answers and it's clear what the result will be, and in particular it must surely be clear to senior executives at this company, who one can assume are not stupid. The result will be that AI-generated answers build towards taking over. Who's that profitable for? This website does not exist for community. It exists for profit.

Comment: @kaya3 - It makes perfect sense. SE does seem to be running the human side of its world-leading EQ&A operation into the ground. I'm suggesting that that's a means, not an aim in itself.

Comment: What is it a means to? It doesn't make the company more attractive to a buyer, even if the buyer does want SE to be destroyed. They won't pay to destroy it if it is already destroying itself for free.

Comment: I think you are missing my point. It's unlikely that the company is destroying itself - or to be more exact, destroying the human-intelligence EQ&A service it has built up, largely using volunteer labour - _for free_. Its owners and senior execs would be stupid if that were the case. Is it likely they're so stupid?

Comment: So, I seem to have read somewhere that the tendencies of AI potential were not suddenly recognized only in November 2022, when ChatGPT got published. That early insights were available to some circles earlier than that. Tim Urban posted about exponential AI acceleration [back in 2015](https://waitbutwhy.com/2015/01/artificial-intelligence-revolution-1.html). I wonder, when in summer 2021 Prosus decided to buy SO/SE, had they been entirely clueless about the role AI was going to play? Or did they make their decision in awareness of the potentials in AI development? What was / is Prosus' plan?

Comment: Why is this happening?

Comment: Ah, thanks for that info. I thought SO/SE was still privately owned. But still, I think I'm on the right lines and the same applies to the current owners, who AFAICS aren't big AI players.

Comment: @Levente and tell: checking out the SO blog entry, [Is this the AI renaissance? (Ep. 564)](https://the-stack-overflow-podcast.simplecast.com/episodes/is-this-the-ai-renaissance/transcript): 1) yeah, [Prosus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosus) has known about AI and its workings for *years*. They also have their own AI team. They have purchased *Udemy*, *CodeAcademy*, and other learning sites. I posit that "the writing's on the wall": Prosus is going to be using these sites' data for its own search/learning system that they can possibly hugely monetize. Soon, no more "volunteers" needed...

Comment: The majority of education in the hand of one monopolistic provider. What could go wrong? We are so done, so, so, so done.

Comment: @Levente: monopolistic and money-hungry! Plus, if international companies are, like US companies, beholden to their shareholders... who cares how it's done, as long as the shareholders are happy

Comment: Thanks, @leanne. So Prosus (owned by [Naspers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naspers) ) do know about AI then. Interesting that they own a big chunk of Tencent which owns Wechat.

Comment: @leanne Until this moment, I was contemplating staying away from SE... from your comment onwards, I am contemplating staying away from the oncoming world. Sounds dramatic but, you know, I am in an invasive and oppressive environment right now where I see how strong appetite people in power have to stunt and throttle the development of others. They try to reduce people into human animals. A world that your insight depicts, combined with my insight here, let me tell you, brings Tesla's quote to mind: "You may live to see man-made horrors beyond your comprehension." I am authentically scared.

Comment: Can you clarify where/what is "old technology" here?

Comment: Since you possibly can't see your vote breakdown, but might be interested in it, I relay that the votes on your post at the time of writing this comment, are: +3/-19.

Comment: The old technology here is conscious thought by skilled craftsmen.

Comment: ChatGPT is definitely a step forward in AI technology, but unfortunately a lot of unskilled people think it has a powerful brain, it does not. Currently it is mainly an artist with words, an electrical parrot so to say. If it gives for example an answer to a question regarding law, it cites non-existing laws, if it is asked to solve programming challenges, it imports non-existing classes. It can copy a bit, just like people sometimes imitates people, with mixed results. Eventually tools improve, but currently the level is insufficient.

Answer (score -92):

**From a longtime SO/SE user: I do *not* support this strike.**

**A company owns this collection of sites. A corporation has the responsibility, and right, to make their own decisions about their properties' functions and appearance. They are *not* beholden to their volunteers regarding their decisions.**

I have seen complaints about "firing" a moderator, the appearance of voting buttons on the sites, and now the disallowance of removal (except in very narrow circumstances) of *perceived* AI-related posts.

As with any company, I'm sure that Stack Exchange Inc's *management* has made decisions based on input and findings *by their employees* as to the best way to proceed.

Just because **some** *volunteers* don't like some decisions, and/or the way they were communicated, *does not mean the company has to do what **the volunteers** want done*. **The company must do what they think is best for their bottom line, *including what **they** think is best for their users.***

I personally, and most people I know, have stopped using SO for any new questions because of the combative way we have been treated *by some volunteers* who believe they know exactly what's right and wrong in every case; who downvote and close [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76368284/1107226) even when they [don't have experience with what's being asked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/424932/1107226). They're *so* professional and knowledgeable that they can somehow magically determine whether a question or answer is valid without any experience in the topic.

**There are a bunch of companies out in the world, including the *creators of ChatGPT*, who are trying to find a way to determine whether something was created by AI or a human being.** If *all of those people* can't even determine 100% if something was created by AI, then **what extraordinary ability do *some* SE volunteers have to determine, without a doubt, that a post's information was provided by AI?**

OMG: instead of volunteering, you should be getting paid the big bucks for this incredible skill!!!

---

**Update:**

After doing some research on [Prosus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosus) and checking out the SO blog entry from April 2023, [Is this the AI renaissance? (Ep. 564)](https://the-stack-overflow-podcast.simplecast.com/episodes/is-this-the-ai-renaissance/transcript): I can say that

- Prosus has known about AI and its workings for years.
- They have their own AI team.
- They have purchased Stack Exchange, [Udemy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udemy), [Codecademy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codecademy), and other learning sites.

Based on this information, I posit that "the writing's on the wall": Prosus is going to be using these sites' data for its own search/learning system that they can possibly hugely monetize. Soon, no more "volunteers" needed...

And, if international corporations, like US corporations, are beholden to their shareholders... well, that's why they seem to not care about their volunteers.

---

**Update to clarify my *update*:**

For those who might not understand what I'm saying about *shareholders* - [Prosus](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/PRX.AS/), owner of the SE/SO collection of sites, is [a public company](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/publiccompany.asp). "Public" means that a company, such as Prosus, provides [stocks](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/stock.asp), aka, a portion of the company that can be purchased by the public or provided to their employees as compensation. The people who own these stocks are called ["stockholders" or "shareholders"](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/shareholder.asp).

Although [these companies are not actually required by law to maximize profit for their shareholders](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8146/are-u-s-companies-legally-obligated-to-maximize-profits-for-shareholders), they often do exactly that - which is why I say "beholden to their shareholders".

What I'm saying with the earlier update is that Prosus can, and likely will, find the optimal way to increase their profits in order to satisfy their shareholders. That may include using the purchased assets, such as SE/SO data, to train AI to teach people to code and to answer their questions - which may or may not make the SE/SO (SO, particularly) sites OBE (no longer necessary).

This has *nothing whatsoever to do with my non-support of this strike* - the reasons for which are in the portion of my post *prior to* the updates. The updates are merely further information around why the company might not be interested in yielding to the strikers' demands.

Comment: *"They are not beholden to their volunteers regarding their decisions."* ─ And we are not beholden to them regarding the hosting of our communities. The whole Stack Exchange model cannot work if there is no agreement that it's in everyone's interests for them to continue hosting us and for us to continue maintaining the value of their product by curating and moderating it. *"The company must do what they think is best for their bottom line, including what they think is best for their users."* ─ sure, and if they want to know what's best for us they can listen to us about it.

Comment: Do you really in your heart believe that Stack Overflow Inc staff always make the correct decisions? That they should take no input from the people that made this network of sites a success in the first place? Software developers who can write and maintain the apps this site runs on are readily found. A legion of people willing to put forth their own unpaid time to actually make the site useful are not readily found.

Comment: The way we are able to tell with greater accuracy than ChatGPT detection tools whether a post is written by ChatGPT, is not because we have discovered some magical solution to the problem that OpenAI are trying to solve, but because the problem we are solving is a different and much easier one. OpenAI want to do it using just the text of the post, whereas we have lots of other input data available, including the original question, the user's post history, and other context; and OpenAI want to minimise both false positives and false negatives, while we mainly want to minimise false positives.

Comment: Hi @leanne. I'm Fred. I've been answering questions on SO from late 2010 to late 2016, and I also have been "curating" the site during this time period. I am aware the private SE company can do whatever they want with their assets, or, as you say, "properties". Problem is, volunteer work is not an asset or a "property". It is not paid for. It is not taxed. It is something one does out of their own time and (sometimes) money. The unique situation the SE company finds itself in is that it _depends_ on distributed, volunteer work, and they cannot easily replace that.

Comment: Again, @kaya3, I'm not talking about the tools. The strikers have made it very clear that they *weren't using tools*. And, regardless of "false positives and false negatives", there are a multitude of sites out there seeking to solve this problem. *Book publishers* are having the same problem, for example. They just want to know that a submitted book was written by a human, not an AI. They also have data such as the history of the contributor - and they *still* cannot tell with any *high* accuracy what is AI and what is human.

Comment: Detecting ChatGPT-generated text can be improved by leveraging human intuition and contextual understanding. Humans possess a vast array of knowledge and experiences that enable them to spot inconsistencies, logical fallacies, and contextual discrepancies in generated text. They can identify nuances, sarcasm, and understand context-specific cues, allowing them to differentiate between genuine human responses and AI-generated ones. By actively engaging with the content, asking probing questions, and critically analyzing the text, humans can bring a depth of understanding that surpasses AIs.

Comment: The parallel with the book publisher would be an author who turns in a new 300-page manuscript every week on topics ranging from tropical fish to child rearing to nuclear physics to spiritual growth to agricultural sustainability to the history of the Incas.

Comment: This post looks like it is just trying to pick up a fight. You don't agree with the strike? Fine, no one here is forcing you - everyone has is views and those should be respected. You, on the other side aren't. Based on your reaction, I assume you are just venting out in frustration. It is clear what your purpose is here:" I personally, and most people I know, have stopped using SO for any new questions because of the combative way we have been treated by some volunteers", so now you are here to talk trash about EVERY volunteer.

Comment: "OMG: instead of volunteering, you should be getting paid the big bucks for this incredible skill!!!" - this line makes your purpose quite clear. You see the volunteers as the ones who did you wrong, and now you are felling a twisted pleasure in seeing them done wrong. I think you may find a far more productive use of your time in reflecting about why you "were done wrong". And I will go even as far as to say that is completely possible that you were indeed punished without reason. But in that case you should just ask the company to review you case instead of being mad at the world.

Comment: Lastly, since you mentioned a "fired volunteer" I suggest that you may want to actually read about that before empty making jokes that only make YOU look quite bad. The "fired  volunteer" as you call it was subject to a slandering campaign on the web that the company started, not just removed from their position. You may thing that they were "fired" with a reason? Again fine. But it is NOT fine to go and make that person you scapegoat puppet in the hope to gain some free advertisement like the company did. So, please. DON'T JOKE ABOUT THAT.

Comment: This answer is a valid contribution. I agree to many points in it except to the first and last one. I support the strike and I don't want to mock moderators. If the company has rights, then the mods have rights too. Of course they can strike at any time. And without their work surely SO as we know it wouldn't exist. We all owe them a lot of gratitude for that. Of course we too can choose freely what to support and what not but in this case I support the strike because the arguments for it convince me. If the company wants a different policy it should look for mods to enforce them elsewhere.

Comment: @kaya3 while your comment is generally accurate, I have seen demonstrations that ChatGPT has a reasonably good conceptual model of sarcasm, and can generate impressive sarcastic prose if you explicitly ask it to be sarcastic.

Comment: @SPArcheon: * Not trying to pick a fight; simply stating an alternative view. * No more or less "venting" than the OP. * Never said "EVERY" volunteer; as a matter of fact, several times said *some*. * Not "mad at the world"; again, simply stating an alternative view. * NOT A JOKE! Yes, I have read the multiple posts and articles about the fired moderator. The point is only that companies have a right to fire people, no legal requirement to explain why, and that their management and employees (such as legal, usually) will make that decision and carry it out.

Comment: @tripleee: the particular publisher I was considering was one that accepts short stories to be placed in an anthology. There are many other examples in the media about companies, colleges, even *TurnItIn* trying to find ways to determine items written by AI. If none of these places has been able to figure out how to tell *with high accuracy*, then I stand by my comment that the volunteers here with this skill should be looking to share it.

Comment: they have the right to "fire" people, revoke moderation rights (since those weren't paid employees in the first place), suspend or ban users. But they don't have any right to go around and tell the press that "there is this moderator that refuses to acknowledge that everyone should be allowed to choose how they identify and was planning to misrepresent users identities on purpose with the sole intention of hurting people, so we removed her and advise no one should hire her ever. BTW here is her mail if you want to send in well deserved hate letters". Yet that is what was done back then.

Comment: @mason: did I say that I "believe that Stack Overflow Inc staff always make the correct decisions?" No, I did not. I said that "A corporation has the responsibility, and right, to make their own decisions..." Those are two completely different things.

Comment: Again, you may have your reason to be angry for some wrongs that were done to you in the past by some mods, I don't have any difficult to believe that. But your post feels like those wrongs are the sole reasons you refuse to recognize while **other mods** are now protesting about other unrelated things.

Comment: @SPArcheon: I bolded and italicized all the salient points. I mentioned the "wrongs" done to me and others because SE/SO has commented that their user count is falling. I believe these "wrongs" are a big reason. And, note that part is *not* bolded or italicized, so why do you think it's my main issue? The rest of the points are simply legal fact, or in the case of AI, publicly discussed issues in the general media. SO/SE is just another company having issues with AI recognition.

Comment: I am open to further elaborate in chat. It is the tone and the chain of arguments you make that hit me wrong. Your premise is that "(the company) are not beholden to their volunteers regarding their decisions"  - that I can agree. Soon after you first mention "complain about firing a mod" - that is already something that involved something they were NOT allowed to do - slandering, and it ended up in actual legal litigation. The final part also I can accept as your view (even if I disagree on some central point) but it is the tone that seem wrong as if you were bashing the volunteers as a whole

Comment: I know you didn't explicitly says that they always make correct decisions. But your post seems predicated on the idea that the company shouldn't accept feedback from their users. That the users should have no say. And that's just silly. It has long been the right of users of a service to boycott that service in order to influence the service provider to change their practices. That's essentially what the moderators are doing here. And it's absurd for you to think that they shouldn't strike (boycott) when the need arises.

Comment: I don't think anyone would say that Stack Overflow Inc must legally abide by what the users wants. But you seem to think that the users expressing their opinions in the form of a strike/boycott shouldn't be supported. You offer no support for that view, other than talking about how the company has a responsibility to make good decisions in order to keep making money, which again none of us disagreed with. What we disagree with is that they aren't making good decisions and they aren't properly collaborating with their users. Theyre chasing short term profits instead of long term platform health

Comment: @mason: again, I did not "explicitly" say any of those things. I didn't say "the company shouldn't accept feedback". A company *should* accept feedback. My point is that what the company *does* with that feedback is its own choice. It is not *required* to comply with what its users/volunteers want. And, yes, the moderators have every right to strike. I simply do not agree with this strike.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes, ChatGPT has been trained on a wide range of text data, including instances of sarcasm. It can often recognize sarcastic statements by analyzing linguistic cues and contextual information within a conversation. However, understanding sarcasm can be challenging even for humans, and there may be cases where ChatGPT might not fully grasp the intended sarcastic tone or meaning, as sarcasm can be subjective and complex.

Comment: @leanne I haven't seen you provided any reasoning for why you disagree with the strike. The only reasoning you seem to have provided is that Stack Overflow Inc is a company and can legally do what it wants - but now that we agree that's true, that still doesn't provide any reasoning for why moderators shouldn't strike. What about their reasoning for striking do you disagree with?

Comment: @mason: I have been following the ChatGPT saga, among other AI-related issues. From all that I have seen/read/heard, there is *no way* that anything - not humans, not tools, not the AI itself - can tell *with high accuracy*, whether content was AI-generated or not. *Some* of the striking volunteers have claimed a near 100% accuracy rate. The company has said that *they* have evidence that many items flagged were *not* AI-generated. This puts the company in an untenable position: lose users from (*possibly*) badly flagged posts, or appease their volunteers by letting them flag unrestrainedly.

Comment: @mason: As to the private rules they had to agree to: if those rules went public, then (*possibly*) users would be able to override the very things the company wants to use to determine if a post is AI-generated. Now, I don't *know* what the private items are, so that's a *guess* on my part. But, I repeat: if these volunteers are truly able to detect AI-generated content with near 100% accuracy, then they need to quit wasting time with a company that doesn't believe them and go get jobs with companies that are desperate to root out AI-generated content.

Comment: You say you've been following that ChatGPT saga, but you either missed or are ignoring crucial parts of this strike. The strike isn't just about ChatGPT - it's about the company having hidden rules, and not coordinating properly with the volunteers. No, they aren't legally required to coordinate with them - but it'd be wise to do so since they're a big part of why these sites are successful in the first place. Several moderators have offered to do blind tests to validate their AI detection abilities - but the company refuses to take them up on the offer.

Comment: If your disagreement with the strike is about whether a human can detect AI generated content or not, then you should have made your answer about that. As written now, it's some rant about how Stack Overflow Inc is a company and can therefore legally do whatever it wants - and that's really relevant to the discussion. Practically nobody disagree with that - it's just that it misses the point and is completely irrelevant. That's why you have so many downvotes here.

Comment: @mason: my post discusses that in the last two points. As for the downvotes, I can't control anyone else's opinions, perception, or translation of the meaning in my posts. Getting downvotes when one expresses disagreement or reasoning that others disagree with has been the normal reality here at SO/SE for a number of years. And, though you likely can't see it, my post *has* gotten some upvotes as well.

Comment: This answer is all over the place. Could you clarify exactly what you mean by "do not support the strike"? Do you mean you think we shouldn't stop donating our free time to improve SE's product? Or do you mean you think SE shouldn't do what we're asking them to do?

Comment: @kaya3: I have explained all my points in the comment thread above, if you care to read it. And, no, I'm not saying that you all should stop donating your time. I also am not saying that "SE shouldn't do what [you're] asking them to do". I am saying, perhaps, that what you're asking them to do (in terms of AI-content flagging) is unreasonable. *Or* that if it isn't, then the strikers should leave. (Perhaps go to that *other* site - or take your AI-detecting skills to companies who respect them.) My update notes that the point may be moot, anyway. Strike on, though, if it's what you believe in.

Comment: Well, if you don't think we should stop striking and you don't think SE should refuse to do what we're asking, then what does it mean to not support the strike? It sounds more like you are just indifferent to the strike.

Comment: Your position would be clearer if you didn't mix it in with irrelevant grievances about other poorly-received changes unrelated to the strike, your own questions being closed, which institutional investors happen to own shares, and so on. It's very hard to discern any logical relation between any of the points you are trying to make, and you seem to be contradicting yourself in multiple ways. So, despite the volume of text you have written, I do not understand what "not support" really means if you don't think we should stop striking, and you don't think SE should refuse what we ask.

Comment: You've said that SE either should or will do what is in their interests, and/or their shareholders' interests, and/or their users' interests. Is there any reason to believe they won't do that? The purpose of the strike is to hopefully change what actions SE will take to serve those interests. Is there a particular outcome you want to achieve, which would be achieved by the strike ending without the strikers' demands being met?

Comment: It comes down to this, @kaya3: a *small subset* of "volunteers" have been closing "thousands" of posts as AI-generated when *there is no one in the world* that has been able to accurately identify AI-generated text. The company has identified that a number of these closings have been incorrect (in alignment with my earlier comment). These volunteers (unreasonably) expect the company to allow them to continue (insensitively) harming users. My "close vote" experience shows an example of unreasonable and insensitive behavior by volunteers. This strike is just a further example of that behavior.

Comment: Further, @kaya3: the company *does not* have to communicate every internal decision with its volunteers. It also *does not* have to expose all of its rules to the public. The "striking" volunteers seem to have conflated themselves with internal employees and management. This isn't about the "love of SE/SO"; this is about trying to force a company to do what a small subset of people want: the ability to close posts and suspend users irregardless of what the company and the larger community sees as harmful.

Comment: OK, so you are wrong, and that's fine.

Comment: Related: The [meta effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect)

Comment: Why do you keep highlighting the word **volunteer** in an apparently condescending way? Just because they are unpaid does not devalue their contributions. Remove the volunteers from the network and see how much "content" remains.

Comment: @Lewis: no condescension intended. Simply separation from the company, employees, or users. **Nowhere, in any of my posts anywhere do I suggest that "[j]ust because they are unpaid", volunteers and their contributions are devalued by me."**

Comment: The company indeed owns the collection of sites, the moderators on the other hand own their (free) time, and thus can decide to strike when they want to. This also is not only because of a new AI policy, but is something that is smoldering for a very long time.

Comment: @leanne  That the company is legally able to do as it wishes with its property is correct. What you said about replacing humans with AI is not correct - and is unlikely to be so for quite some years yet.  | I'm an SE EE moderator - because I care for people and seek to help newcomers get things right and understand the system. I've also seen the damage uncontrolled newcomers and AI answers can do. [See my answer above](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390372/285552). The use of AI for question improvement may work. I guarantee that it's use for question answering will be (and is) a disaster.

Comment: To leanne I would like to point out: tough [censored]. It doesn't matter whether you support a strike or not. That decision is made by the people striking. If working doesn't feel valuable to a volunteer, they'll stop volunteering, and you cannot force them to volunteer, because that is called slavery. If you want people to do work for you, you either pay them, or you make it worth their while some other way, like the warm fuzzy feeling of doing good in the world.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon: very likely, eventually AI will outsmart people, but the current level (like ChatGPT) does not and is way off. That is basically because how these tools are made: as electrical parrots that imitate humans, and for example refer to sources, classes, laws. But the difference is, these do not exist. Indeed, it refers to them because somehow it is trained that there is a country with a certain law related to the question, whereas for the exact question, the "real" country has no such law.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon:  I refer to [Overflow Labs](https://stackoverflow.co/labs/) where Prosus is already using AI to locate questions in existing text and suggest titles for new questions. Since Prosus owns the likes of Udemy and Codecademy, they can get new questions at any time. With the AI's help, they can cut the number of people needed to deal with low-quality questions dramatically. Yet, they can still grow the SO database of programming-related questions effectively and without human judgement (read "bullying") that so often happens in long-standing forums. AI is here...

Comment: @leanne Yes, I largely agree with your comments on question improvement. I covered this reasonably well (I hope :-) ) in [my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390372/285552)

Comment: What seems to be happening here is that SE moderators in general believe that they can do work of sufficient quality without the help of LLM software, while the SE management disagrees. This is just another instance of what will inevitably occur as more and more so-called "AI" and "robotics" entities are used to replace human workers ... irrespective of whether the workers are paid or are volunteering. Sadly, over time, human workers and human volunteers are going to lose this war, as an increasing number of people will find themselves out of work due to being replaced by machines.

Comment: As someone who largely agrees with your sentiment on "volunteers toxic", I find the answer absurd. **StackExchange = community**. It's nothing without it. I also don't _fully_ support the strike (if including Prompt Engineering SE), but my reasoning is very different.

Comment: In the years have been active here, typically the most vocal users complaining about moderators "abuse", were the ones not willing to put any effort investing into the reputation gamification and good quality questions both on technical and English content, while still demanding good quality answers, often abusing the system with drive by users.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: I have never gotten into the reputation gamification *because of* the moderator abuse. For example, one of my early questions, regarding Visual Studio 2012, was closed as a duplicate of a question for a much older, inapplicable, version of VS. I see new developers referred to SO for help, only to find their limited tech vocabulary gets them slammed with downvotes and questions closed without explanation. If I defend valid questions (example in my answer), I get slammed, when even the moderators don't agree on a reason for close and/or don't have topic knowledge. Why invest?

Comment: @leanne there were no moderators involved in the handling of the referenced question.

Comment: @KevinB: then other "volunteers" - regardless, the point is the same. (That's why I generally put "volunteers" in quotes: because there are many titles.) The issue, though, is the same: SO has become an unfriendly environment unless you can ask just the right questions in just the right way to avoid a tidal wave of downvotes and/or closure without explanation - even if you've never asked a question before.

Comment: SO has always been a site with standards, that isn't something new that occurred. It's what attracted experts to come here rather than continuing wherever they were prior to SO. Unfortunately, as the site grew standards stopped being enforced as well resulting in more negativity as we lost the ability to curate the site the way it needs to be.

Comment: @KevinB: I'm not talking about standards. I'm talking about basic kindness and concern for new, or new to a topic, users. Questions can be corrected to standards - *if* explanation is given and closure is held off to give time. The example I gave had not a single explanation for any of the downvotes, and the *original* closure reason wasn't even correct. You, yourself, were involved in the discussion, and still the problem wasn't fixed. The question is still closed, and the (first time) user is probably long gone at this point. *Standards* for a new user were *not* followed.

Comment: @leanne if you're talking about basic kindness, why do all of your references not show any signs of rude behavior or actions that are against the standards of the site?

Comment: @KevinB, the example is all about rudeness. Downvotes without explanation: not rude? Almost immediate closure for an invalid reason: not rude? All moves against a first time user: within standards for the site? My meta question about reason for closure and how to re-open getting a multitude of downvotes and no help: not rude? C'mon Kevin: really?

Comment: Those are design problems with the site that we've been pushing for solving for literally a decade. This isn't a community problem, the site literally tells us to downvote not useful content and not to comment on downvotes.

Comment: I 100% agree that the site does an *awful* job of onboarding users and displaying information to users related to how their question is being received. That's been a problem for as long as this site has existed. They've made multiple attempts to solve it, but it seems as if they gave up on the QA side of things ~ 8 years ago.

Comment: No, @KevinB; those are "volunteer" problems. I visited your "close voters" chat and saw that all the close voters were together having a visit. So, "smokescreen", or like tools, pop up messages into the room, whereupon somebody decides to close the question, and others run right over to close. There was even one discussion about whether a user was "worth keeping" in order to make a close decision. That's plain *wrong*.

Comment: have you even looked at the posts that smokedetector presents? it's a spam tool. it finds spam. literal spam. now you're just making claims about things you didn't even take the time to investigate. This tool exists, again, because the company wouldn't do it themselves.

Comment: @KevinB: *or like tools*

Comment: The only thing the automated tools that exist in that room do are 1: find spam, 2: find rude content. that's it. I would expect those to be things you'd appreciate existing, given your concerns on rudeness. Actual rudeness, not "Someone on the internet didn't like what i created, it's not fair"

Comment: @KevinB: again, the point is that *people*, like yourself, make the decision to close. *People* give the reason for closure. *People* give the downvotes. *People* decided to close the example question *without understanding the topic in the question*, then refused to reopen it, even though a person with knowledge of the topic (myself) demonstrated how the question was valid and relevant - unless because it didn't specifically involve code, it was off-topic, upon which *people* could not agree.

Comment: All you need is a consensus that agrees with you. you didn't have one. One person saying everyone else is wrong is unlikely to be correct.

Comment: @KevinB: one person with knowledge of the topic, with a consensus of people who had no knowledge of the topic, and refused to hear the relevant point. Typical SO "volunteers". Majority doesn't mean correct: example, incorrect SO answers upvoted hundreds of times. Listening and understanding would be "correct".

Comment: Sure, however, no one here just gets to claim they’re the expert, it’s earned. You presented your case, and people disagreed. That’s the system working as intended.

Comment: @leanne The gamification is not perfect per se, however people who has high points did not get them overnight and had to start somewhere as everyone else.Posting quality questions take time. Low quality, unmoderated content would not be attractive to visit, alas the feed is boring as it is, and that is an unappreciated and ungrateful free work I also gave up on doing. Answering also takes time. I am not also very interested on interacting with drive through users. SE and drive through users seems to think the only ones accountable to standard and rules are high rep users who play by the rules.