# A user seems to be trolling many SE sites with AI-generated answers; what should I do?

Tags: discussion, chatgpt, tag-abuse

[This user](https://stackexchange.com/users/6123746/serg-z) has had an account on a number of Stack Exchange sites for many years, and wrote a small number of questions and answers in that time. In the last few days, they've started posting dozens of answers per day across many SE sites, and they're joining more sites every day.

I think these answers are AI-generated because

- Many show telltale signs of it (others are ambiguous).
- Until recently their bio said "At the moment I am studying C# to implement some ideas in AI and internet communication." After I mentioned that in a couple of comments on answers of theirs, they rewrote it; now it says they're an "amateur provocateur", and the tone in general is mocking.
- They recently commented "I am just trying to help people to see the damage new policies led to. We wouldn't have this if not for moderator's strike!" and "It's all for greater good. Of course it'll be banned, but that's the price to make them address the problem sooner" (both on [this answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/80505) which is now deleted). I should add that I don't really believe they have altruistic motives, since they also write mocking comments in a style similar to their current bio, and things like "you should also spend time on your development instead of this pointless gpt witch-hunt. Time is precious, my friend". It seems more like 4chan-style trolling.

My question is not "what should be done about this", but what *I* should do, as someone who wants this to stop but has no special powers.

In normal times I would flag the most egregious answer on each site and let moderators deal with it, but these aren't normal times.

I can downvote each offending answer once on some sites they've joined, and zero times on others, but I feel like it does little good. There's an endless stream of new answers, I don't have much reputation to spend on some of the sites, and if I'm not careful I might get dinged for serial downvoting.

I could write comments or site-meta posts or chat messages on as many sites as possible to encourage others to join in the downvoting, but I'd rather not, partly because it would be a lot of work, but also because I'd feel somewhat unsafe being their most active enemy – though perhaps that's irrational.

I have been hoping for the last couple of days that someone else would do something about it, but that doesn't seem to be happening. There aren't any downvotes at all on many of the answers.

Obviously writing this question on Meta counts as doing something, but I don't think problems like this should be handled by writing one Meta question per problem user.

Comment: Welcome to Meta SE. FYI, the Math meta [User spamming chatbot answers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35868) post is about this user's spamming type activities, but just specifically on the Mathematics SE site.

Comment: That user has been suspended network-wide for a month.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the moderators on strike specifically requested that users supporting the strike **do not** engage in deliberate acts of vandalism or disruption on SE/SO.  If you want to support the strike, vote, comment or post constructively on Meta when the issue is discussed and/or withdraw from some activities on the site.

Comment: The user was suspended and yet has added new answers only 10 hours ago https://stackexchange.com/users/6123746/serg-z?tab=activity. How is that possible?

Comment: @S.Catterall [Apparently](/q/257498) a user suspended at the network level can be unsuspended on individual sites by moderators.

Comment: @benrg Thanks, I didn't realise that was possible. It could also be that the answers were submitted by the user via alternative accounts, which were then subsequently merged.

Answer (score 28):

Someone who is purposefully causing disruption and controversy, and/or isn't engaging in use of the site in good faith, is in violation of the Stack Exchange [Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct) (specifically see 'Inauthentic Usage') regardless of whether or not they used GPT.

> We do not allow any use of the system that violates our Acceptable Use policy or directly causes unnecessary and unwanted disruption and/or harm to users and/or the network.

Please report these activites per usual channels (flags, primarily), and if the problem is serious enough, the Contact Us form is a backstop that will put you in contact with the Community Management team. In this case, however, no need to report further -- I've got it from here.

Comment: I believe that flags normally go to moderators, and, with the moderators on strike, shouldn't a regular user go directly to the CM/Contact Us option for now?

Comment: @Slate It's great that you responded so relatively quickly, and will handle taking care of this issue. Also, FYI, the Math meta [User spamming chatbot answers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35868) post is about this same user's spamming type activities, but specifically just on the Mathematics SE site.

Comment: @JonathanZonstrike I can't give a general answer to your question because most sites on the network still have at least one active moderator. Routing all conduct issues through the CM team is also just not practical nor will it lead to beneficial outcomes. So I'd encourage folks to be judicious about doing so, though the option is always open. The OP's situation, however, is standard CM territory, since it concerns disruption occurring across multiple sites.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thanks for the information, I'll leave a link to this answer in a comment on that question.

Comment: @Slate "Routing all conduct issues through the CM team is also just not practical nor will it lead to beneficial outcomes."  Not to put too fine a point on it, but that is, you know, kind of the point.  If moderation continues without having any impact on the CM team or the company at large, then the strike really isn't doing its job, is it?  I don't have anything against you or the rest of the CM and T&S teams, but the whole point of not moderating is to force you guys to do the work, thus pointing out how important we volunteer moderators are to the well-functioning of the site.

Comment: And well - being able to moderate AI content the way it should *is* the heart of the strike. It is unfortunate the individual mentioned chose to make their protest *that* way but this is *literally* the sort of thing that we want to discourage people from doing , just  less ironically.

Comment: Almost a month ago, I made a similar [flag on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/11379709), which is still pending. The user give me an ["inauthentic answer"" on the Anime & Manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/68086/56635)(see ChatGPT deleted answer), to which I commented that I won't accept it and asked him to rewrite the answer in him own words. However, the user deleted the answer along with two others on the same site, which were posted almost simultaneously. (1/2)

Comment: I was browsed user's network profile and noticed that he had posted on Anime & Manga, SO, and Ask Ubuntu simultaneously, so I flagged him on Stack Overflow. During this time, the user issued several code-only answers to disguise their lack of originality.(2/2)

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, the reason for suspension is rudeness and admitting causing trouble. But if a user were to have a similar pattern of answers, but keep a straight face and always be polite "Sorry you feel that way, but I am just trying to help the OP and give an answer", then the same answering behaviour would be fine, and no action could be taken?

Comment: With all due respect, @Xander, that is not a reasonable request. What do you actually suppose drowning a handful of CMs, making them miserable in their daily lives by expecting them to handle every single conduct issue on the platform, would accomplish? No -- we are going to prioritize our work. I am not going to endorse any steps that would risk causing hard feelings to fester rather than heal. We are a proactive and responsive team. If you want the right things to be seen first, I strongly suggest _you_ prioritize what you send to us, too.

Comment: @Fillet I'm not able to answer a hypothetical. The only thing I can say is that I'd encourage any moderator evaluating a user's actions to be holistic in their evaluation. There's no reason to allow a user to disrupt a site / the network just because they claim they're doing the right thing.

Comment: @Slate I did not claim that it is reasonable.  A strike action is a *response* to an unreasonable request from management.  Unreasonableness is met with unreasonableness.  I understand that you sit between the volunteer moderators and the administrative structure which is the "real problem".  That is a hard position to be in, and I don't feel *good* about dumping work on you.  But the point of the protest action is to demonstrate, in a meaningful and concrete way, the work that is done by the moderators.  If it is effective, it is going to hurt someone, somewhere.

Comment: @Xander The volume of work you are asking us to do will not be done, it's as simple as that. My colleagues and I are professionals with jobs to do; we will come into work, we will do our work, we will leave work at the end of the working day. If we have too much to do, we are going to ask our managers how we should prioritize the tasks we have to do, do the best jobs we can, and then leave at the end of the working day. This is reality.

Comment: @Slate "The volume of work you are asking us to do will not be done..." Yes.  I know that is likely.  What is the current flag count on SO right now?  On Math SE, it is almost 800.  This *also* represents a volume of work which isn't being done.  And *please* ask your managers how to prioritize the work.  Maybe that will help get the message across that there is work which isn't being done, but which *needs* to be done.

Comment: @Xander Are you saying you expect Community Managers to handle every single work item to make a point, or do you actually believe that and believe we'll have failed your expectations if we don't do all of it? I need to understand if you are making an abstract point about undone work, or looking me in the eye and telling me I should work double or triple the hours I did last week.

Comment: @Slate I think that its more that a pile up flags in general, and things that were previously done by striking mods, and *unfortunately* crappy things like spammers and trolls not being handled effectively - is a concequence of flags. And frankly, I suspect when there's a successful resolution of the strike, the mod teams will be making a very loud sigh, and the ones not burnt out by all the preceding drama will be quite enthusiastically dealing with what's piled up. Burning out CMs isn't a goal here. I don't think there's an expectation for CMs to handle *all* the flags

Comment: But a loss of mod eyes due to the strike on the short term does affect your visibility of what's going on on street level. And the flags *are* piling up, and things will be missed.

Comment: @Journeyman Then I strongly suggest folks stop talking about this situation as though the CMs should be solely responsible for handling everything that is going missed. In time, the mod action will have passed. And when it does, people will remember comments folks left conveying a callous disregard for our individual well-being. Comments like these risk souring a working relationship with CMs -- the community's primary internal advocates -- for years to come. I don't want that outcome.

Comment: We can nudge, we can encourage, we can influence. But telling people what to think or what to feel is difficult. Especially considering the ebb and flow of events, and the sheer level of frustration going on. And I think the risk of burn out is *just* as acute for folks outside the company who're trying to work for a better working relationship and constructive communication when decisions are made which affects the goals we're trying to reach. We're here *because* there was a failure in communication and common goals.

Comment: Decisions were made that have *already* soured the working relationship between the community and company - which was hopefully in the process of healing. I'd add, the good ones *leave* when they've had enough. A few manage to hold up enough hope and maybe stupidity to figure "maybe we can fix it". I'm not blaming the CMs for what was missed. I'm blaming the *situation* for things being bad.

Comment: @Slate "Are you saying you expect Community Managers to handle every single work item to make a point, or do you actually believe that and believe we'll have failed your expectations if we don't do all of it?"  No, and no.  I think that the *company* has failed to meet the expectations of the community.  As a moderator, I am powerless to speak directly to power.  The most I can do is choose not to do my job.  You are the next in line to deal with the crap that we moderators are not dealing with.

Comment: I get that, @Journeyman, but if a 'better working relationship' looks like folks telling us we should have worked longer hours, handled more, done more, on posts where we are handling on-site issues (this is not the first time this has occurred), then I don't know what to say. Identifying me and my colleagues as 'unfortunate collateral in a bad situation' does no one favors.

Comment: I am not asking you to do the work that we aren't---if you do all that extra work, then the company may decide that volunteer moderators aren't necessary for the site to function, and may *permanently* dump all that work on you.  No one wants that outcome (probably).  Rather, the moderation workload is piling up.  Presumably, management would like *someone* to deal with that backlog, eventually.  If it is currently piling up on your todo list, than, perhaps, you could make the point to management that it is not sustainable in this manner...

Comment: and, like, the company actually *needs* volunteer moderators, and should, you know, maybe *listen* to us when we raise concerns.

Comment: Basically, what I am saying is that moderators are currently passing the buck to the CM team.  My expectation is that the CM team will pass the buck to their managers, and maybe, eventually, the higher ups will get the message.

Comment: @Slate when the strike ends, we'll probably spend about 5 minutes grumbling and then getting back to work. In about a week or two, whatever mods are left will probably have sorted out the problem.  We don't want you to work longer hours. We'd love for you to have the resources to get things *done*. We'd like the backlog of stuff we'd like the company to get looked at rather than you looking at the backlog of things we should be handing but won't  (Cause of the strike) , cause we don't feel trusted to handle the things we should be can't (which resulted in the strike).

Comment: On the other hand, we've literally brought up things like 'we don't have enough CMs' - and other issues that we feel would make *your* life easier with... apparently less success than we'd like? I was happy to see a growing team, and *progress* before the recent set of dramas. If you're working longer hours, and can't keep up, and this has been going on for *years*, how can we better convince the people who can give you the resources to meet our needs? And on our end,  there's a lot of unhappiness over how the company seems to see us. How do *we* fix these things?

Comment: At the start of this conversation, @Xander, you told me "the whole point of not moderating is to force you guys to do the work." I believe this was a pointed remark and I believe it landed in the way that was intended. If you want to discuss this further, we can continue this in your mod chatroom.

Comment: @Slate I don't think Xander's comment was meant in the spirit you're taking it. We know your team is being forced to handle the brunt of this, and that's not really fair to you. What is fair, though, is that in the absence of volunteer moderation, the work falls to the company. The impossible tasks you describe are indeed impossible without volunteers or a substantial investment from the company. Since the latter seems extremely unlikely, especially with recent CM layoffs, the company's only other option is to keep the volunteers happy.

Comment: @Slate If the company chooses to make CMs miserable with overwork instead of solving the disconnect with volunteers, that's fault of your bosses at whatever level of the hierarchy is making these decisions.

Comment: @Slate "You guys" is inclusive of the CM team, the T&S team, your managers, their managers, and everyone on up to the CEO.  Again, I don't feel particularly good about dumping work on the CM team, but if volunteer moderators aren't doing the work, who is going to do it?  And again, the CM team is stuck in the middle.  But what is the alternative?

Comment: @Slate - I'm only speaking for myself, but I expect you to look after yourself, and not engage in any deathmarch-style heroics to make up for the company's failures. And I asume that users will continue to expect actions that maintain a high-quality web-site and community to be done, and there won't be enough people to do them, and the quality of StackExchange sites will degrade.

Comment: Most people in tech have seen a CEO get a dumb idea and drive a successful enterprise into the ground in pursuit of it before. It's important that users and employees protect their interests and don't pay too much of a price for that, no matter how much we value the organization, our position in it, and the benefits we get from it. I assure you that any serious user here wants you to be doing well in your job at SE, but I hope you realize that we are all in a sh*tty situation here.

Comment: The alternative here @Xander is that CMs report to their managers that the volume is too great for them to make up the difference, their managers pass this (or a sensible translation) up the chain, and eventually TPTB get the message that they aren't Elons, that refusing to communicate on-site while dissing mods in the press is creating problems for their own staff and driving people away from the sites, and the company gets serious about resolving this stupid, stupid, completely unnecessary situation and we can all move on.

Comment: @Shog9 Yes, exactly.  Normal users and moderators have the ability to send a message to the CMs and to T&S.  Those teams, in turn, have the ability to send messages to their managers, and so on.

Comment: Yeah, figured we were on the same page @Xander, but wanna underline that the important outcome here is *not* that CMs burn out in some heroic effort to reify some exec's BS delusions. That's not gonna happen. It's laughable that anyone would *think* that, much less send it to a reporter. But here we are, the cracks are showing, and what good folks like Slate here need more'n anything else is encouragement to work their 9-5 and *not one minute more*, lest any of the cost of this idiocy fails to land upon the heads of those who wrought it.

Comment: @Slate I think Xander point was not that the CMs permanently do all the work, but that when it gets too much (and it seems that line was will and truly crossed some time ago) that instead of that stress and pressure being pushed back onto striking mods, that it gets directed upwards until the penny drops with your managers.

Comment: @Slate just one more voice chiming in to clarify that the last thing we want is for you guys (CMs) to burn out. We want you to do the jobs you are paid for and work the hours you are paid for _and not one second more_. Since the strike is creating much more work for y'all, our hope is that you will not do that work since, as you correctly point out, that would not be healthy for you to say the least! We then hope this will trickle up the chain of command until someone who can actually take decisions finally realizes that volunteer work is essential for the network.

Comment: Serg Z. created [Apricotie Hunt](//stackexchange.com/users/29114562/apricotie-hunt) and continued their old behavior. Those accounts are now deleted, but some of the answers remain, now credited to Serg Z. Today they created [another account of the same name](//stackexchange.com/users/29128978/apricotie-hunt). You said you'd take it from here – should I continue to flag their posts, or just wait for the wheels of justice to grind slowly? I tried Contact Us, but they just sent back a (presumably canned) reply telling me to use flags.

Comment: I flagged one of the second Apricotie Hunt's answers. The flag was resolved as helpful, but as far as I can tell, they did nothing but delete the answer that I flagged, even though I made it clear that it was only an example of a larger problem. Please consider deleting all answers by all of these accounts. I don't know whether it would discourage Serg Z., but at least it would (if done regularly) limit the damage to a fixed amount instead of an ever-growing amount.

Comment: @benrg Thanks for the report. I'll look at this today.

Answer (score 17):

As a normal user, there is nothing you can do except for the things you have mentioned in your question. Flag their posts for moderator attention, and once the strike ends, the problematic user will be dealt with.

I would recommend not engaging with the user directly. At best it would be a waste of your time; at worst they could start attacking you with serial downvotes or any other means at their disposal.

Answer (score 14):

> My question is not "what should be done about this", but what I should do, as someone who wants this to stop but has no special powers.

Probably the best way to resolve the issue is to [join the strike](https://openletter.mousetail.nl/). The demands of the strikers resolve this precise issue by resuming bans of users posting GPT answers which are harming the community knowledge base.

If you choose not to join the strike, you can raise flags, but bear in mind this is a workaround, not a fundamental solution. Without a full team of moderators with the ability to enforce site policies, spam of various types can't be dealt with holistically over the long term.

> They recently commented "I am just trying to help people to see the damage new policies led to. We wouldn't have this if not for moderator's strike!" and "It's all for greater good. Of course it'll be banned, but that's the price to make them address the problem sooner"

I don't trust the comments by the GPT spammer--they're almost certainly not acting in good faith. If they are genuinely trying to support the strike, their actions are unhelpful and misguided. Actively sabotaging the site discredits the strike's cause by muddling actual rates of GPT spam.

Comment: Yep. Disagreement doesn't justify vandalism.

Comment: There's always a strong possibility that "comments by [a] GPT spammer" are themselves ChatGPT generated.