# Chat flags for room owners?

Tags: discussion, flags, chat, notifications

Recently it happened that a familiar high-reputation user from another room came into one where I am RO and notified me that there were flagged messages. I thought that if you were in a room and supposed to keep it clean would be able to see flags as well to be notified about stuff that should not be there.
The high-rep user informed me that one needs to be above 10k reputation or moderator to see flags (or has to have it raised in the first place).

While checking for duplicates my first stop has been the post [A guide to moderating chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271267/a-guide-to-moderating-chat) where it reads as well:

> When you flag a message as spam/offensive, the flag will draw the attention of other high-reputation community members, as well as moderators. In both cases, they’ll be asked to determine if the flag is valid or not

While I support the reputation threshhold I wondered why roomowners would be excluded from the flag notification. And if that would be too much it should at least be visible for the room owners that currently are paying attention.

I could not find any negative consequences while thinking about it

- Noone would be super annoyed (mods and high-rep users already get notified) because the flags would be visible or there would be a notification for flags in rooms someone is owner of.
- It provides RO with a little bit more information about what is happening. It is kinda strange to see "a lot" of people rushing into a room because there was something flagged and have no clue what happened.

The trigger message (by a user who joined the chat for the first time) was something along the lines of "service/framework XY is dumb as fuck" (cannot quote the exact message because it was removed and I moved the message to one of the bins) if that was relevant. I did not see it as an offending message so I did nothing furtheron. Only after said user joined, I moved it.

To make my question(s) clear: Why are the flags in a room not at least shown to the room owners? Is that something one could/should implement?

(Tagging this discussion for now, because I am unaware of potential other pros/cons from users that are more experienced with the network)

Comment: Given that ROs are supposed to help moderate the chatroom, they should have access to review flags in the room they are RO in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem, in my opinion, is not *seeing* the flags, but rather *act upon* the flags (i.e. casting valid/invalid vote). That's a power I don't want users with low reputation to have.

Room ownership can be given with 100 reputation only. That means, with the association bonus, that a user with zero experience on a site and little experience elsewhere can become RO.

Sometimes it's hard to decide if a message is really offensive, **in the context of the site and its culture**,  not only in the context of the room. That is why it's better to trust only users with 10k reputation with handling the flags.

I won't mind letting room owners only see flags in their room, but that will require non-trivial development effort, and not sure it's worth the time. As you mentioned yourself, there are more than enough high rep users across the network (and moderators) who come to those flags.

Comment: Fair point. On the other hand in the rooms where this really would be relevant, room owners only get "accepted" after they spent a decent amount of time there. While you might be right with this being an edge case I think there are a lot of room owners in some of the bigger rooms below 10k reputation to which this might be relevant. And there sure are situations where there is none of the 10k users active and this might be relevant. As said, I get your point though.

Comment: @geisterfurz007 agree in your specific case(s), but keep in mind such change can't be selective.

Comment: Sure! That is why I put on discussion and not feature-request :)

Comment: How about adding the feature for ROs with experience, for an instance that those over 3k or 2k are allowed to act upon the flags. 100+ would be able to see, 2k|3k+ would be able to act upon them.

Comment: @Zoe yeah that would be better, but still not trivial to develop.

Comment: Yeah indeed. It actually turned out that the person seemed to be a troll which I ended up kicking. If that is possible he might have even flagged himself...

Comment: This doesn't make any sense to me. While I agree with most of your points, particularly the third paragraph, that seems to be a reason why you would not given room ownership to a new or low-rep user. It is not a reason to hide flags from a person who is obviously trusted enough to be granted RO status, yet happens to have 9.5k rep.

Comment: @CodyGray like I said, I have no problem with letting RO see the flags, the problem is only with acting upon them. Room owner isn't a real power, most they can do to other user is kick out for a minute. They can't chat ban other users, and they can't even delete messages after the two minutes window pass, so having threshold of 100 is fine.

Answer (score 2):

One of the chatrooms I'm active in makes extensive use of room owners to help moderate the place.

Firstly, as an active RO, if you see something wrong *you should be acting on it*. You're kind of the one on the ground, seeing things happen. Flags are kind of meant for situations where you need back up. You don't need flags for that. You should be dealing with it

Secondly in *some* cases ROs may not always use their powers appropriately. In a practical sense, this gives 10kers some oversight (even if they arn't a RO), reflecting  how someone's trust depends on what they've achieved. On the other hand, a RO *could* hide evidence of things that shouldn't happen on a room over the long run - and its happened.

So, if you're an RO, you don't need it, just eyeball MK1 and common sense. *You're* the community's eyes on the ground and don't need a third party telling you where trouble is.

Comment: Yes the flags can be used by RO's if they need backup. But they can be used by anyone else as well which is not notifying RO's. But I guess I will go with ShadowWizards answer that it is rather an edge case then anything else. Thanks for your thoughts on the topic. Btw. It turned out that the person has been a troll anyways and I ended up kicking him... If that is even possible he might have flagged on his own.