# The [vampire] tag kinda sucks -- can we stake it?

Tags: discussion, meta, burninate-request

I just noticed [vampire](/questions/tagged/vampire) wandering out in the daylight. In theory it *could* be [help-vampire](/questions/tagged/help-vampire), but it's really a meta tag (about people) that needs to go away.

There are only 11 posts so I can get rid of it over a week or two, but I'm wondering if that's something we should be doing?

Comment: maybe rename to help-vampire and then make it a synonym of [tag:etiquette]?

Comment: Perhaps also a [[stake-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stake-request)] for dealing *with* [help-vampire]s.

Comment: tag renames/merges are more complex than nuking the tag, ironically

Comment: Is it partially because the term's rude like 'rep-whore' and similar stuff? That sounds to me like a decent reason to discourage the usage of the word in general.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Vampire tag has been staked. Got little help from Sonic.

At some point the tag should be a small pile of dust in the sunlight.

Comment: So it will be killed at 3am? What a bad time for a vampire to die. It is DARK outside!! Good job though.

Comment: It's bright somewhere

Comment: That’s a good point. // I think I will ask a question today or tomorrow whether the term „help vampire“ should be discouraged as Chair wrote.

Comment: There's already one: [What's a kinder way to stake a help vampire?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315622/whats-a-kinder-way-to-stake-a-help-vampire)

Comment: After scanning the answers they seem to be more focused on how to handle them and not how to call them (although this is also what you asked.)

Comment: Yup.... But I can't think of a good alternative