# Is [spoonfeeding] a meta-tag? Is it really a relevant meta meme?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, burninate-request

I added this [spoonfeeding](/questions/tagged/spoonfeeding) to a question I posted a few moments ago, before that question, it had four questions closed.

I looked at the FAQ about the Meta Memes, and spoonfeeding is not included.

There aren't tags for all Meta Memes.

Only my question is asking about "spoonfeeding". The other question uses the term but does not make questions about spoonfeeding.

This tag doesn't look to serve a purpose that can't be filled by searching [spoonfeeding](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=spoonfeeding). This search returns 30 results.

#### Tag Wiki

##### Tag excerpt

> Spoonfeeding is the meta meme name for giving the answers to questions asked by users who haven't done any noticeable research.

##### Tag body

> Spoonfeeding is the meta meme name for giving the answers to questions asked by users, who haven't done their homework by learning the basics of programming, searching the web for answers, or trying to do something on their own before asking here.

Should this tag be burninated? (removed from all the questions). If not, what should we do to improve the tag wiki?

## Related

### Tags

[fastest-gun](/questions/tagged/fastest-gun), [gaming-the-system](/questions/tagged/gaming-the-system), [meme](/questions/tagged/meme), [fun](/questions/tagged/fun), [terminology](/questions/tagged/terminology)

### [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)

- [The Many Memes of Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19478/289691)

Comment: Why do you think it's a meta tag? Do you [think it means different things to different people](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/tagging) or that it can't work as the only tag on a question? If so why, if not, why?

Comment: Most tags on Meta SE literally can't work as the only tag on a question, because one of [tag:discussion], [tag:support], etc. are always required.

Comment: @RobertLongson The tag wiki doesn't provide usage guidance. That is obvious. What does this tag mean to you? How do you suggest that this tag be used? I added this tag to my question because I asked if *spoon feeding* is appropriate when replying to user's request for moderator to explain a rule beyond what is reasonable. Do I used the tag properly?

Comment: ...Is there a particular reason we shouldn't have meta tags on meta sites?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I think any tag not having clear usage guidance might be a meta-tag and might be removed. Anyone who wants to keep a tag should ensure that the tag usage guidance is clear, putting the best interest of the community first. Adding a tag wiki with a definition might help in certain cases but I'm unsure if this one of those cases. Tags should be used to help experts that might answer a question to find those questions. Who are our experts on spoonfeeding? If it is used as meta-tag, what is the usage? Does it helps as to find questions to find the origin of the meme?

Comment: Tags are meant to make posts easier to find. Spoonfeeding in a sense is a phenomenon we face on sites, rather than a meta tag or a meme.  I also feel like over time, the community has gotten more serious - so something 'fun' once might not be as accepted by community on meta as it once was.

Comment: @kaya on Meta we mean the only other tag on a question, except for the mandatory ones.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see any value in the [spoonfeeding](/questions/tagged/spoonfeeding) tag.

We should burninate it same way other such tags, e.g. [vampire](/questions/tagged/vampire) have been [burninated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322998/the-vampire-tag-kinda-sucks-can-we-stake-it) in the past.

Answer (score -2):

In general, the various informal and poorly named slang terms like "spoonfeeding", "help vampires", "MCVE", "XY problem", "FGITW" etc are not helpful. All of these have some background story where at some point in time, someone subjectively invented a poorly-named term for a phenomenon and then it stuck.

The goal of the various metas across the network isn't to build some secret society with special handshakes and initiation rites etc. But rather to host a discussion where as many users as possible can participate. Therefore we shouldn't force new or old users to stop and scratch their head just because they are facing strange, unfamiliar terms not appearing anywhere else outside SE. Weird abbreviations are particularly unhelpful.

Better to spell out the true intent. "Replying to no-effort questions", "users repeatingly seeking help without any putting effort into research" or how else one might spell these out... I'm sure someone else can come up with more eloquent ways to do so without resorting to mysterious analogies or abbreviations.

Jokes and memes is another thing, but I don't really think "spoonfeeding" is a meme.

Comment: I don't understand from this answer if you support removing the tag, or not. Please focus on the actual question which is "should the tag be burninated", or at least add a TL;DR in the beginning.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsSadAndAngry During burnination (another of those terms), we may discuss the value and purpose of a tag without every question being a clear yes/no stance. Doing so is more valuable than a yes/no post without any arguments or rationale put forward...

Comment: @Lundin of course, but if it's not clear from first reading what is the actual opinion, I don't think it's a good thing.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsSadAndAngry So how exactly is this answer unclear? It takes a clear stance against the use of any of these terms. The conclusion would be that no corresponding tags should exist either. I kind of expect the reader to be able to add 1 + 1 together...

Comment: The term "XY problem" is incredibly helpful for communicating about questions where the asker has jumped to a conclusion and assumed that the solution they're looking for must be of a particular form, when the better solution to their underlying problem actually takes a different form. Calling such problems "XY problems" is in no way analogous to terms like "help vampire" or "spoonfeeding", because "XY problem" refers to the formulation of the question as opposed to the personal character of the person who asked it, and it is not pejorative.

Comment: @Lundin when the question is Yes/No I expect the answer to say either Yes or No, not go in circles. I want to know its essence without having to read it several times. So yes, I find such an answer not appealing to read. It's very common practice to add a "TL;DR" on top saying exactly that, then going onward with details to those who wish to read further. I don't understand why you're so against it, but that's your call.

Comment: @kaya3 The problem with "XY problem" is the name - it is such a fuzzy nondescript term that you have to explain what it actually means every single time it is used. "This appears to be XY" isn't a helpful comment. "This here is a strange solution. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve with this solution?" is a helpful comment.

Comment: @Lundin "XY problem" is neither fuzzy nor non-descript; it has a specific meaning, the only issue is that people don't necessarily know what its meaning is; but the same is true of every specific term used in computing. "This is an XY problem" is no fuzzier and no less meaningful than "this function is asynchronous", which is likewise useless to someone who doesn't know what the term "asynchronous" means. That's not an argument against using a term like "XY problem", it's an argument for explaining the term; but most people already do, by linking to https://xyproblem.info/ when they comment.