# Is it okay to delete questions that get poorly received?

Tags: discussion, questions, down-votes, self-delete

I've recently learned about "Help Vampires" as a concept.  It's something that's easy to forget about until I see a `-1` attach to a question I ask on Stack Overflow, and I instantly feel the blood in my mouth.

I assume most down-votes are good faith indicators from peers that I've asked something inappropriate, poorly worded, or poorly researched, and will delete the question if I see more than a few.

But I wanted to ask here, is that appropriate behavior from me?  It's not a selfless act, having a poorly received anything sitting on the internet is stressful and removing it is a quick escape.  I want to believe it undoes any damage upon the community by de-cluttering it, but I always worry that someone may be in the midst of typing something important and I'm rudely cutting them off.

Is it a problem at all to delete a badly received question very quickly?

Comment: If you're worried about a question ban, then deleted downvoted questions will count against you. But I'm not sure if that's what you mean?

Comment: @bobble - Oh, I didn't realize that was a metric.  I guess that answers my question then, if there's an entire system in place for it.

Comment: @ Anne, it's mostly to catch people who repeatedly make bad questions which are downvoted/closed/deleted. Not for someone who made a mistake once.

Comment: If a question can be fixed with edits then that is always preferable to deletion. I supposed you could delete it, edit it into shape, and then undelete it as long as you do it within 30 days. (After 30 days, you no longer have a link to deleted questions from your profile.)

Comment: Given the [meme of the lost key](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397) I wouldn't bother too much about a single downvote if you verified your question is clear, well-researched and useful for future visitors. Besides the help center and the [checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648) you might check what the downvote ratio is for the tag you posted on. Rumor has it that every other Go question on SO gets a downvote. That is great for the tag (high quality) but might leave some OPs disappointed. If you get close votes, that is better addressed instantly with an edit.

Comment: @rene I've downvoted posts by accident a few times. I do retract the vote within the grace period. However, there are also posts that get deleted *almost immediately* after a downvote. Often I'd start a comment to explain something wrong in the post and it gets deleted because it receives a downvote. From me or otherwise. I fear that some day I'd downvote by accident and the post will be deleted before I can retract that vote...

Comment: @VLAZ don't worry, glad you told us. Going forward we will assign all blame to you for  questions that got deleted after a downvote ...

Comment: @rene Thanks...I choose to view this as being promoted to Tim's keys. Feels like a step up.

Comment: Isn't the [HV word](https://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/) now officially taboo (not a rhetorical question)? Wasn't there some MSE post about it? I couldn't find it.

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q no, I don't think so. You're confusing it with the term used for users that focus on gaining as much reputation as possible, whatever it takes.

Comment: @VLAZ I tried some stats on deletion at the same day a question also got a single downvote: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1435517 given the size of SO that number doesn't seem very high. So I wouldn't get too much focused on preventing your accidental dv to lead to a delete vote.

Comment: @rene I'd prefer if people didn't delete their questions almost immediately after one downvote. As I said, sometimes I've literally been in the middle of writing a comment that might have lead to an improvement.

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q maybe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315721 ?

Comment: @VLAZ yeah, order is important: comment first, dv later.