# Chat's "Ignores" moderator page is broken

Tags: bug, status-declined, chat, moderator-tools, 500-server-error

On all the chat domains, the moderator page has a link to the path `/admin/users`, and the tab "Ignores" on that page is broken, which simply throws and display a HTTP 500 server error page.

I couldn't find a prior bug report about this yet.

Broken pages (requires moderator privileges on the relevant server to test; others will get a 404 error):

- https://chat.stackoverflow.com/admin/users?tab=ignores
- https://chat.stackexchange.com/admin/users?tab=ignores
- https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/admin/users?tab=ignores

Comment: Does this still not work?

Comment: nope, nope, nope.

Comment: Huh, had no idea mods could see who users are ignoring.

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMaskV2 Not per se. They can see the number of users ignoring a particular user, and a ranking of such.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog they can access the "prefs" tab of a user's chat profile and that lists users that user is ignoring, but yeah there's no way I'm aware of to see on a profile a list of users that are ignoring *them*. (it is just on separate page which basically lists users with a count of how many users are ignoring them - but that's as specific as it goes... or not given this bug report :p)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data for user ignores is stored in a way that is causing the query that supplies data for this page to time out (in my testing, it takes over 40 seconds to complete on prod). In order to change this, we would need to change the entire mechanism by which we are recording user ignores (and then backfill and update every function that touches it). Unfortunately, we don't have the resources in the foreseeable future to be able to address this. So I am declining this request and hiding the tab in the admin chat panel.

> Chat admin controls
> Which one is ignored the most?
> Requires refactor

Comment: Now this is a feature I don't mind seeing going away. :)

Comment: You can backlog it for when you overhaul chat into this century ;)

Comment: Removing the link is also an acceptable outcome. Thanks!