# Is there a "test" chat room?

Tags: discussion, support, chat, testing

I'm looking into a *possible* bug in the SE chat system.  To do this, I need to be able to send a bunch (10+) of chat messages.  I don't want to bother anyone.  Is there already a "test" chat room in which this would be appropriate, or would it be best to just create a new one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each chat server has a Sandbox room that you could use for this:

- [On chat.stackoverflow](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1/sandbox)
- [On chat.stackexchange](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1/sandbox)
- [On chat.meta.stackexchange](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1196/sandbox-trash-bin-something)

You could use one of those three, or make your own, it doesn't matter all that much. If they're frozen, you can raise a [chat flag for moderator attention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271268/369802) asking a moderator to unfreeze them.