# Can I unstar a message if I'm the room owner?

Tags: support, chat, chat-stars

Can I unstar a message if I'm the room owner (RO) by clearing the stars (assume that I only starred)?

Is that possible?

Comment: RO = room owner?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A guide to moderating chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271267/a-guide-to-moderating-chat) (Specifically [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271267/a-guide-to-moderating-chat/271269#271269))